# How to error handle 1004 Error with WorksheetFunction.VLookup?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code:

```
Dim wsFunc As WorksheetFunction: Set wsFunc = Application.WorksheetFunction
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("2012")
Dim rngLook As Range: Set rngLook = ws.Range("A:M")

'within a loop
  currName = "Example"
  cellNum = wsFunc.VLookup(currName, rngLook, 13, False)
```

VLookup is not expected to always find a result; but when it does not find a result the line errors out before I can even error check it the next line.

The error:

> Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class

It works fine when a result is found. What's a good way to handle errors here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a way to skip the errors inside the code and go on with the loop anyway, hope it helps:

```
Sub new1()

Dim wsFunc As WorksheetFunction: Set wsFunc = Application.WorksheetFunction
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets(1)
Dim rngLook As Range: Set rngLook = ws.Range("A:M")

currName = "Example"
On Error Resume Next ''if error, the code will go on anyway
cellNum = wsFunc.VLookup(currName, rngLook, 13, 0)

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
''error appeared
    MsgBox "currName not found" ''optional, no need to do anything
End If

On Error GoTo 0 ''no error, coming back to default conditions

End Sub
```

Comment: If the VLookup function is in a for-loop you can clear the error each loop by: `err.Clear`

Answer (score 67):

Instead of `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup`, you can use `Application.Vlookup`. If you set a `Variant` equal to this it returns Error 2042 if no match is found. You can then test the variant - `cellNum` in this case - with `IsError`:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("2012")
Dim rngLook As Range: Set rngLook = ws.Range("A:M")
Dim currName As String
Dim cellNum As Variant

'within a loop
currName = "Example"
cellNum = Application.VLookup(currName, rngLook, 13, False)
If IsError(cellNum) Then
    MsgBox "no match"
Else
    MsgBox cellNum
End If
End Sub
```

The `Application` versions of the `VLOOKUP` and `MATCH` functions allow you to test for errors without *raising* the error.  If you use the `WorksheetFunction` version, you need convoluted error handling that re-routes your code to an error handler, returns to the next statement to evaluate, etc.  With the `Application` functions, you can avoid that mess.

The above could be further simplified using the `IIF` function. This method is not always appropriate (e.g., if you have to do more/different procedure based on the `If/Then`) but in the case of this where you are simply trying to determinie what prompt to display in the MsgBox, it should work:

```
cellNum = Application.VLookup(currName, rngLook, 13, False)
MsgBox IIF(IsError(cellNum),"no match", cellNum)
```

Consider those methods **instead of** `On Error ...` statements.  They are both easier to read and maintain -- few things are more confusing than trying to follow a bunch of `GoTo` and `Resume` statements.

Comment: +1 Much better than the accepted one, (which btw needs an `Err.Clear` when `Err.Number <> 0`).

Comment: When I type `Application.`, Vlookup does not show. Any help?

Comment: @krobel, try using it even though it doesn't autofill. I can't remember if that will work but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @DougGlancy tried, but it doesn't work. Won't compile.

Comment: @krobelusmeetsyndra, I read recently that VLOOKUP is being discontinued and that there is a new XLOOKUP function. It hasn't made it to my laptop yet, but maybe it has on yours. Does VLOOKUP still exist in Excel itself in your version? if so, then I don't know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @DougGlancy it does exist. Don't know why it's not working either... anyway, I used the `On Error Resume Next` approach. Thanks for the attention, tho.

Answer (score 2):

From my limited experience, this happens for two main reasons:

1. The *lookup_value* (arg1) is not present in the *table_array* (arg2)

The simple solution here is to use an error handler ending with `Resume Next`

2. **The formats of arg1 and arg2 are not interpreted correctly**

If your `lookup_value` is a variable you can enclose it with `TRIM()`

> cellNum = wsFunc.VLookup(**TRIM**(currName), rngLook, 13, False)