# Get the Vlookup Property of the worksheetFunction class

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

My Vlookup Formula is giving an error

> "Unable to get the Vlookup Property of the worksheetFunction class run
> time error 1004"

Here is my Code

```
Me.Txt_Rate.Value = 
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.cmb_Product.Value, 
sh.Range("C:J"), 2, False)
```

Please Guide

Comment: Did you try putting all of that on one line? It looks like you have it broken into 3? Is `sh` a variable that you have set somewhere else? Or has it not yet been set?

Comment: I usually use `IsError()` to trap these kind of errors. Here is an example. See [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67646591/how-can-i-input-same-value-in-place-of-vlookup-n-a)

Comment: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057369/vlookup-in-vba-within-a-for-loop) is nother way to handle the same issue using `OERN`

Comment: Use the late-bound versions of the Excel functions: `Me.Txt_Rate.Value = Application.IfNa(Application.VLookup(Me.cmb_Product.Value, sh.Range("C:J"), 2, False), "Not Available")`. If the value is not found, `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` will **raise the mentioned error** while `Application.VLookup` will **return the 'not available' error** (`Error 2042`).