# VBA vlookup in external workbook

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I am trying to get my code working but it is still showing some errors. The code is to, from workbook1, open workbook2 and insert vlookup function in workbook1 which will search values from workbook1 in the range from workbook2 the code is as follows:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim fNameAndPath As Variant, wb As Workbook
fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Wybierz plik do kontroli rabatu")
If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath)

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets("ICOS").Activate
Set lookupvalue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(3, 3)
Set rngLookupRange = wb.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("$A:$P")

   Range("C3:C300") = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookupvalue, rngLookupRange, 16, False)
```

what is wrong in this code? is shows "unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class"

thanks

Comment: Your Lookupvalue is being set as if it is an object, which I don't think the formula will accept. try declaring the Lookupvalue variable as a string and remove the Set keyword when you populate it and see if that works.

Comment: Take a look at the second answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063214/how-to-error-handle-1004-error-with-worksheetfunction-vlookup. May be as simple as just removing the .Worksheetfunction part from Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookupvalue, rngLookupRange, 16, False) - this works for me

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here:

lookupvalue should not be an object, but a value, such as a string, double, integer.
Change the corresponding line to

```
lookupvalue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(3, 3).value
```

Secondly, the Vlookup function returns only one value (or a #N/A). It does not return a range. So change the next line to something like

```
Range("C4").value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookupvalue, rngLookupRange, 16, False)
```

Comment: thanks!

i have changed what you said to, but the error is still up.