# Userform VLOOKUP not working

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying to extract the employee name based on the employee id with a `VLOOKUP` formula in a User Form.

The code below inst working.

```
   Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()        
   Label4.Caption = Sheet1.Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TextBox1.Text, Range("A:B"), 2, False)
   End Sub
```

Comment: What's the problem? is it not working? Add some content to your question

Comment: yes its not working its giving me this message " unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class" error 1004

Comment: See  Doug Glancy's comment here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063214/how-to-error-handle-1004-error-with-worksheetfunction-vlookup

Comment: @pnuts I appreciate you oppinion. Thanks for responding.

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky re-read dougs post.

Comment: @brettdj Which post do you mean? And did you re-read my post below before posting your comment above? You confuse me...

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky You had made a comment (now gone) saying this Doug's post was on `Application.Vlookup` not `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`therefore this was not the answer, also that for some reason you thought `Application.Vlookup` was undocumented and not supported. Doug's approach is the efficient way, see [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/callingworksheetfunctionsinvba.aspx)

Comment: @brettdj All the solutions (Doug's, Pearson's, and the one below (I wrote it without doing any prior reading or search...) are *the same solution*. And it works well indeed. So if I did ever say it was not the answer I was clearly wrong. As for the "Application.Vlookup", it does not exist but thank god for the very forgiving and understanding VBA compiler.

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky No, they aren't the same ..... which is why Doug managed to avoid the error handler you needed to use. And of course `Application.Vlookup` exists, this is by design not chance. See [here](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/09/24/the-worksheetfunction-method/)

Comment: @brettdj First, it’s a 10+ year old post. Even then, Doug honestly indicated that an error “Error 2042” is actually raised (but apparently it is not added to the VBA error stack). So what do we have here? An old, undocumented and not supported (for decades now!) “original(?)” method of the Application object that still (miraculously) executes, does not properly handles the error that does occur but rather sweeps it  “under the rug”... Hmm... Honestly, I would not touch it with a ten-foot pole. You are, of course, free to do, say and believe whatever you wish, my friend—it’s your business...

Comment: What exactly is the relevance of the 10 year post - still valid information which you clearly weren't aware of. Anyhow like Ron I won't be drawn into any further wasteful exchanges with someone who seems overly anxious to prove their point.

Comment: "...overly anxious to prove their point..."

Answer (score -1):

The provlem here is when there is no match found. That's the cause of the error message. Here is the
the VBA code you should use:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    Label1.Caption = Sheet1.Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TextBox1.Text, Range("A:B"), 2, False)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Label1.Caption = "not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks man for giving the time and help me in problem , actually the input what you have added is great thanks , but this also does not solve my problem m i can't see the result shown in the label1 caption maybe something wrong with the excel file kindly note that the sheet called sheet1 and i have the employee id in A and the name in B and i have created a user form having a text box , label and a button. Basically i want the end user to write the employee id and click on the button and in label it will show the result. can somebody help.

Comment: That exactly what this code takes care of. I assume it is in the userform's module, right? I recreated it all as you described and it just works. I cannot think of anothing that should prevent you from seeng the same results as I do. Troubleshooting, troubleshooting, troubleshooting... that's the ticket. Good luck.