# How to return the value of vlookup in same cell in which the value to be looked up is entered?

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I want to return the result of **vlookup in the same cell in which the value to be looked up is entered**. Figure 1 shows the value which is to be looked up

**Figure 1**

[image]

I want the value in A1 to change to vlookup value of t001 when I press enter as shown in figure 2

**Figure 2**

[image]

the lookup table is present in sheet2 t001 trew
                                      t002 rty

Following code I have written but it is not working; kindly help me in this regard

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A114")) Is Nothing Then
    If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Target.Value) Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Table2 = Sheet2.Range("C2:D3")
        Target.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target.Value, Table2, 2, False)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using

```
If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Target.Value) Then
...
End If
```

You are making sure that the interior of the 'if' clause will not be executed if the target value is not a number. For example having Table2

```
abc ¦ not working
-----------------
123 ¦  working
```

after typing 'abc' nothing happens and after typing 123 the number disappears and 'working' appears

Comment: if any value is not present in vlookup table then it breaks the code but i want it to accept the entered value if vlookup value is not present

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063214/how-to-error-handle-1004-error-with-worksheetfunction-vlookup

Comment: Code is working fine. In case the data is not present in lookup table a msg box appears, I want to add an option that _if i click on close window cross of msg box it will clear that cell content and if I press ok it accepts the entry_.