# Word/Excel Vba vlookup "Subscript out of range" error

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to use vlookup to read a string from a word document and return corresponding values from an excel sheet. I seem to be getting a "Subscript out or Range" Error on the vlookup function.

This is the worksheet that i am looking at:
[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPgMZ.png)

The code I have is:

```
Sub Autofill()
Dim oExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim testdb As Excel.Workbook
Dim testvar1 As Double

Set testdb = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("k:\SIF\Vibration\Dbase.xlsm")

testvar1 = oExcel.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Roger", testdb.Sheets("Main").Range("A1:C4"), 2, False)

MsgBox (testvar1)

End Sub
```

I tried using the Application.Vlookup function as well, to no avail. Got the same error.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but have you tried declaring oExcel as Excel.Application?

Add this before setting testdb, 

set oExcel = new Excel.Application

Comment: You'd likely get this error if the name of the sheet `Main` doesn't exist in the Dbase.xlsm file. Maybe there's an extra space or something, check for accuracy. I emulated your code and it appears ok. One thing that might be an issue is if you are expecting to return a string, you may want to change testvar1 to be a `String` and not `Double`.

Comment: I suspect you are getting your error because your `Vlookup` returns an error (since not found), you need to add error handling in cases your `Vlookup` is unsuccessful, see link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063214/how-to-error-handle-1004-error-with-worksheetfunction-vlookup

Comment: i think you need to `activate` the excel window after open() and before .vlookup. based on my experience

Answer (score 0):

This script worked for me. Make sure the Main tab exists, that's how I duplicated the error.

A missing value in the VLookup will give you "Unable to get Vlookup property..." error.

Comment: My sheet name in the workbook and the code was identical and the workbook was not hidden. Still didnt work with the oExcel.Workbooks.Open(), so then I replaced with GetObject() and it worked.

Could you have an idea why this would happen?

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure without being able to experience it first-hand (which I would love to). A couple longshots I have is there is an unreleased COM object VBA did not release from memory or it could be environmental. Perhaps there is a workbook_open() process in the workbook?