# VBA Elseif statement leading to a runtime error

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to run my code, I get a runtime error (1004) when running line 7 (2d Elseif)

```
If InStr(1, Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:AAA20000").Cells(i, 1), "Car", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then 'si le lieu est une source alors on cherche ses coordonnées dans l'onglet source
    startv = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:AAA20000").Cells(i, 1).Text, Sheets("Sources").Range("A2:AAA2000"), 5, True)

        If (InStr(1, Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:AAA20000").Cells(1, j), "Gare", vbTextCompare) > 0 And WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:AAA20000").Cells(1, j).Text, Sheets("Embranchements ferroviaires").Range("A2:AAA2000"), 6, True) = "Oui") Then
                    endv = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:AAA20000").Cells(1, j).Text, Sheets("Embranchements ferroviaires").Range("A2:AAA2000"), 5, True)

        Else:
                    startv = vbNullString
                    endv = vbNullString

        End If
End If
```

The text value that gives me a runtime error is "App2", which is linked to a "Non" in its sheet (as opposed to the "Oui" that is one of the conditions I am testing). I don't understand why it doesn't work since none of the conidtions are met, it should just move on to Else:.

Any clues ?

Thanks,
Doule

Comment: See if you can replicate the error with only that line of code, and then remove elements from the line until you isolate where the error is (e.g. which side of the `and`, then which method on that side etc)

Comment: I tried Gare2, Gare3, App1 and App3 and all four give the right result. The problem seems to be when a "Non" is linked to App, which isn't a problem for "Gare". I'm guessing it is because it is trying to look for "App" in the "Gare" sheet, leading to a runtime error. Is there any other way of fixing it other that writing to "if" statements ?

Comment: Just a note, but I suggest: Instead of `Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:AAA20000").Cells(1, j)` use `Sheets("Distancier").Cells(1, j)` • And what is the exact error message?

Comment: I'll change that, will make the code easier to read thanks ! The error is : Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

Comment: @Doule so if the extra lines of the code are irrelevant to the problem, remove them from the question i.e. the M of [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (but do test the the reduce code still produces the error). Also if you want to make it easier to read, store `Sheets("Distancier")` in a variable.

Comment: Removed the first two. This still gives the error. Since it is going to look for "app" in a sheet where there is no mention of "app", vlookup returns #N/A which produces the runtime error. Should I just seperate the two conditions i have in my if statement or is there an elegant way around #N/A ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to error handle 1004 Error with WorksheetFunction.VLookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063214/how-to-error-handle-1004-error-with-worksheetfunction-vlookup)

Comment: I thought about adding an errorhandler but "resume next" would mean that is still enter the If statement. I guess the easiest way here might just be to split the if statement into two seperate if's.