# Excel VBA VLookup Run-time error '1004'

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, vlookup

I want to consolidate two sheets. In `Tabelle 3` is already some data. Therefore, I defined the `Next Free Row (NFR)` and want my data from `Tabelle 5` added to the next free row in `Tabelle 3`. Therefore, I wrote the following VLookup function.

```
Sub ConsolidateData()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim NFR As Long

lastrow = Tabelle5.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
NFR = Tabelle3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-3).Row

Set myrange = Tabelle5.UsedRange


    For i = 4 To lastrow


        Tabelle3.Cells(NFR + i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle5.Cells(i, 1), myrange, 1, False)


        Tabelle3.Cells(NFR + i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle5.Cells(i, 1), myrange, 2, False)


    Next i

End Sub
```

Even though, I'm already using this code in a different workbook, where it works smooth, it doesn't work here. Instead `Run-time error '1004'` occurs for this line:

```
Tabelle3.Cells(NFR + i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle5.Cells(i, 1), myrange, 1, False)
```

Does anyone see the mistake or can tell me what I've coded wrong?

Comment: Why Offset(-3) for the definition of NFR?

Comment: @CFO  I have to set `i=4` because in `Tabelle 5` my required data starts in `row 4` . In case I'm transfering it like that to the `NFR` in `Tabelle 3` there would be a gap of 3 rows. Therefore I `Offset(-3)` rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `Vlookup` cannot find value you are looking for and therefore throws an error. `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` will return error '1004' if value cannot be found. Please consider following test:

- Put in cell A2 value of 15.
- Run below macros

macro 1:

```
Sub test1()

check = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(15, Range("A1:A5"), 1, False)

Debug.Print check

End Sub
```

macro 2:

```
Sub test2()

check = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(1, Range("A1:A5"), 1, False)

Debug.Print check

End Sub
```

As you can see second one throws an error. To overcome that issue you should change `WorksheetFunction.VLoookup` to `Application.VLookup` and implement error checking:

```
Sub test2()

If IsError(Application.VLookup(1, Range("A1:A5"), 1, False)) = False Then

check = Application.VLookup(1, Range("A1:A5"), 1, False)

End If

Debug.Print check

End Sub
```

Please look here as well: [How to error handle 1004 Error with WorksheetFunction.VLookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063214/how-to-error-handle-1004-error-with-worksheetfunction-vlookup)