# Vlookup into a closed Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm creating a spreadsheet to view a single product extracting values from a closed workbook (products.xlsx), using the SKU as a lookup value.

This code runs into:

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

I'm developing the spreadsheet to manage WooCommerce Products using Excel for our company's online store. Our need is to view a single product and be able to edit or delete it and also add more products even though the database is not within the current workbook.

```vb
Sub get_data_form_another_workbook()

    Dim databook As Workbook
    Dim test As String
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Open database in the background
    Set databook = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\products.xlsx")
    
    ' loop through database table to get required value
    ' AND THIS IS WHERE I'M GETTING AN ERROR
    test = Application.WorksheetFuncion.VLookup(Range("product_current"), _
    databook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:F"), 4, 0)
    
    ' Test
    Debug.Print test
    
    databook.Close
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What does "Open database in the background" mean? What a "closed" workbook should mean for you, since you open it using `Set databook = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\products.xlsx")`? What is`"product_current"`? A named range? If so, does it contain a single cell? Please, try `Dim test As Variant` and see what it returns in `Immediate Window`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA VLookup Run-time error '1004'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044056/excel-vba-vlookup-run-time-error-1004)

Comment: Hi... thanks for your answer... Uhm, by opening in the background I mean, opening an excel workbook that has 1 sheet and in it, a list of products... 

I tried using Variant and also changed Range("product_current") to Range("AE6") to test using a cell reference instead of named range... and now the error says it's out of range...

Comment: I guess that `databook's` active sheet hasn't got a range named `product_current`. Do qualify it properly e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("product_current")`. Also, if there is no match, an error will occur. Rather use `Application.VLookup` whose result you can test with `IsError`. To write an answer, we would need to know where the range `Range("product_current")` is located (worksheet and workbook) and if it's in the workbook containing this code.

Comment: Make sure the value you are searching for exists. Also, because yu are working with SKUS, I've seen thousand of times SKUS coded as numbers or text. Make sure both (list and value searched) are same type (number/text)

Comment: Also it's `worksheetfunction` not `worksheetfuncion`

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008 Tried that it still says Out of Range...

Comment: The product_current range is located in the index.xlsb (Scope: workbook) and I'm trying to extract values from products.xlsx (databook)...

@FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns what data type would you suggest I use... because I tried string and then tried variant... also fixed the worksheetFunction typo it still says out of Range

Comment: Scope workbook is nice, but you need to activate the workbook for it to work i.e. if the workbook is the workbook containing this code, then you can do `ThisWorkbook.Activate`. Otherwise, you'll have to do `Workbooks("index.xlsb").Activate`. But best is what I suggested in my previous comment. What's the big deal in not revealing the worksheet name and in not clarifying if `index.xlsb` is the workbook containing this code?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the responses... I edited the code a bit and it seems my mistake was on referencing the sheets properly... In the products.xlsb, the sheet I was trying to reference is "data"... Changed "Sheet1" to "data" and it worked...

```
Sub get_data_form_another_workbook()

    Dim databook As Workbook
    Dim test As Variant
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Open database in the background
    Set databook = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\products.xlsx")
    
    ' loop through database table to get required value
    test = Application.VLookup(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("product").Range("product_current"), _
    databook.Sheets("Data").Range("A:F"), 4, 0)
    
    ' Test
    Debug.Print test
        
    
    databook.Close
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```