# How to reference Tab in Vlookup?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

This is making a compile error. I believe I am not pointing to the Tab that contains my 'table_array'.

This is the formula without values, Table_Array
[image: This is the formula without values, Table_Array]

The highlighted section I believe I am doing wrong, my tab is called 'CATMAP'
[image: The highlighted section I believe I am doing wrong, my tab is called 'CATMAP']

Comment: Please add your code formatted as code block. [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `Worksheets(CATMAP),Column."A:B"` is no valid syntax.

Instead use …

- `Worksheets(CATMAP).Range("A:B")` if `CATMAP` is a variable.
- or `Worksheets("CATMAP").Range("A:B")` if `CATMAP` is the name of your worksheet.

Also the way you use `L2` means that `L2` is a variable name. If you want to use the value of cell L2 than it must be something like `Worksheets("CATMAP").Range("L2")`.

Additionally I recommend to read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Not using `.Select` at all is a very good practice and prevents many errors.

Comment: Thanks Answered in the next post, still need some help though!

Comment: The error occurs if the value you look for isn't found. Have a look here [How to error handle 1004 Error with WorksheetFunction.VLookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18063579/3219613)