# If Not IsError(MATCH) is not bypassing the error. How to skip unfound MATCHes?

Tags: excel, vba

Aim: Find column headers input into Array `Headers` and then copy those columns onto a new sheet.

The raw data has 200+ columns and fetching them manually is a no-go so this just searches the first row for the header in question with `MATCH`. If the header is not found, I am getting `RTE 1004: Application-defined or object defined error` on the `HeaderLoc = Match` line.

I have tried to change HeaderLoc to Variant to allow for it to assume an error value but this is not working.

My error trap `If Not IsError` line is not being reached - I have also tried to put the error trap before assigning `HeaderLoc`

---

**How do I get the error to move on without using `On Error`?** Also, this solution seems to be in align with many others accepted solutions here, so wondering why it's not working here but does in other instances. Is it due to the way my array is assigned?

---

```
Dim HeaderLoc as Long
Dim Headers   
Headers = Array("Header1", "Header2", Etc........)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = LBound(Headers) To UBound(Headers)
        HeaderLoc = WorksheetFunction.Match(Headers(i), Raw.Rows(1), 0)
            If Not IsError(HeaderLoc) Then
                Raw.Range(Raw.Cells(2, HeaderLoc), Raw.Cells(LR, HeaderLoc)).Copy
                Des.Cells(2, i + 13).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
    Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Try `Application.Match`, that allows you to trap and check the error I think.

Comment: declare headerloc as variant

Comment: @ScottCraner tried that - that is in question ;)

Comment: this was in addition to @SJR recommendation.  do both.

Comment: Re the duplicate: it is about the [most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064104/11683), not the accepted one.

Comment: @GSerg thanks - I was only searching for `MATCH` solutions which is why I didn't stumble across that. So this is what it feels like to have a question closed **cringes**

Comment: @urdearboy Why? Duplicates are [good](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32315/147640).

Comment: @GSerg hadn’t considered that. Thanks for sharing the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either skip the error and test for `0`

```
Dim HeaderLoc As Long
Dim Headers

Headers = Array("Header1", "Header2", Etc........)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = LBound(Headers) To UBound(Headers)
        HeaderLoc = 0
        On Error Resume Next
            HeaderLoc = WorksheetFunction.Match(Headers(i), Raw.Rows(1), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
            If HeaderLoc > 0 Then
                Raw.Range(Raw.Cells(2, HeaderLoc), Raw.Cells(LR, HeaderLoc)).Copy
                Des.Cells(2, i + 13).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
    Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Or use Application.Match and a variant variable.

```
Dim HeaderLoc As Variant
Dim Headers

Headers = Array("Header1", "Header2", Etc........)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = LBound(Headers) To UBound(Headers)
        HeaderLoc = Application.Match(Headers(i), Raw.Rows(1), 0)
            If Not IsError(HeaderLoc) Then
                Raw.Range(Raw.Cells(2, HeaderLoc), Raw.Cells(LR, HeaderLoc)).Copy
                Des.Cells(2, i + 13).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
    Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```