# VBA Match Function Finding Value That Doesn't Exist

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have a bit of VBA code that performs a match to a different worksheet. The row that is returned from this match is then used to determine the outcome of an `If` statement. Here is my code:

```
On Error Resume Next 'Accuracy Index Match Start
aMatchRow = Application.Match(summarySheet.Cells(accuracyRow, 3), aCommSheet.Range("C:C"), 0)
On Error GoTo 0

With summarySheet.Cells(accuracyRow, 15)
    If aMatchRow > 0 Then
        .Value = aCommSheet.Cells(aMatchRow, 15)
    Else
        .Value = "COMMENT REQUIRED"
    End If
End With
```

The issue I am having is that even when there is not a match, a value is being returned. So for example, in a scenario where `summarySheet.Cells(accuracyRow, 3)` does not have a match in `aCommSheet.Range("C:C")` I am still getting a row value returned, which is then fed into the `If` statement, so the wrong value is returned to `summarySheet.Cells(accuracyRow, 15)`.

In the event that there isn't a match, the "ELSE" should be carried out. But the "If" is being carried out no matter what.

Comment: `Application.Match` [does not raise an error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064104/11683), so the `On Error` statement plays no role. Instead it returns a `Variant/Error`, and `aMatchRow > 0` would raise error 13 "Type mismatch" if `aMatchRow` contained a `Variant/Error`. If it does not raise, that means it always finds something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @GSerg's comment:

```
Dim m
m = Application.Match(summarySheet.Cells(accuracyRow, 3), aCommSheet.Range("C:C"), 0)


With summarySheet.Cells(accuracyRow, 15)
    If Not IsError(m) Then '<<< test for no match here
        .Value = aCommSheet.Cells(m, 15)
    Else
        .Value = "COMMENT REQUIRED"
    End If
End With
```

Comment: I adjusted the code to 

`With summarySheet.Cells(accuracyRow, 15)
        If Not IsError(aMatchRow) Then
            .Value = aCommSheet.Cells(aMatchRow, 15)
        Else
            .Value = "COMMENT REQUIRED"
        End If
    End With`

But still have the same issue

Comment: I had aMatchRow declared as a Long. After changing that everything works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: I [stand corrected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54812563/vba-match-function-finding-value-that-doesnt-exist#comment96402047_54812563). The `On Error` statement did play a role, it hid the error 13 upon trying to store a `Variant/Error` in a `Long`, so `aMatchRow` would retain its original value.