# WorksheetFunction.Vlookup returns error in a For-Each loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to code vlookup using WorksheetFunction to perform as usual vlookup in Excel (dynamic cell that is to be searched and dynamic cells to input results).

```vb
Sub vlookupFunction()

    Dim cl As Range
    Dim searchManagersRange As Range
    Dim rangeToSearchManagers As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rangeToSearchManagers = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
    Set searchManagersRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).UsedRange

    For Each cl In rangeToSearchManagers
        On Error GoTo managerNotFound
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(cl.Offset(0, 16).Address) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, searchManagersRange, 2, 0)
    Next cl

managerNotFound:
    cl.Offset(0, 16).Value = "#N/A"
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

Code works fine and completes the search, but in the end it returns object variable not set...error, as cl is "Nothing" in the end.

Comment: so it's a range error or a value error?  `if cl.value <> "" then` do this code in your for each loop to prevent the value error (instead of error handling with `goto` put this in the Else statement)... if range error, then i'm lost because you defined your range, unless the last row is 2?

Comment: @Uros Djukic is there a reason for using sheet index instead of sheet name?

Comment: @Error1004 No, I am just trying to test something so sheet name is not important at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Application` instead of `Worksheetfunction` and you can "trap" the error without "raising" it, and remove your messy On Error/Resume statements.

Read eg [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063214/how-to-error-handle-1004-error-with-worksheetfunction-vlookup) for more info.

```
For Each cl In rangeToSearchManagers
    cl.Offset(0, 16).Value = Application.VLookup(cl, searchManagersRange, 2, 0)
Next cl

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid `Loop`

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .Range("Q2:Q" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2," & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Name & "!" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).UsedRange.Address & ",2,0),"""")"
    End With

End Sub
```