# How can I set values for empty results for VBA VLookup function?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to use a VLookup function which gets values from another sheet in the same workbook. There are records which are not present in the searched table array and I want to set a value for them but I am getting the following errors.

When I use the following WorksheetFunction.Vlookup I get Run-time Error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

```
for rowNum = 2 to lastRow
    targetSheet.Cells(rowNum, 15) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(targetSheet.Cells(rowNum, 1), Sheets("Source Table").Range("A1:C100"), 3,0)
Next rowNum
```

When I use `Application.VLookup` instead of `WorksheetFunction.VLookup`, this time I get Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Comment: Use an Error Trapping routine.  Check VBA HELP for `On Error …`

Comment: Wouldn't it be: `WorksheetFunction.VLookup(targetSheet.Cells(rowNum, 1), Sheets("Source Table").Range("A1:C100"), 3,0)`

Comment: `VLookup.Cells` is not valid code regardless of whether it's `Application.VLookup` or `WorksheetFunction.VLookup`. For how to handle the "not found" errors, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064104/11683. You should not be getting "Type mismatch" when assigning a result from `application.vlookup` to a cell, even if it does not find anything.

Comment: I made a mistake above. It is not Vlookup.Cells(...) in the code. It is Vlookup(targetSheet.Cells(...)...)