# Why am I getting Run time error 1004 using Vlookup?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro where I go through each row of Newest_closed worksheet and:
 - get the NCASTS string in column A
 - look for the string in Newest_opened worksheet using Vlookup
 - if found, get contents of Column K and call it "Resp_Unit2"
 - paste value of "Resp_Unit2" in Column K of Newest_closed worksheet
NOTE:  Newest_opened and Newest_closed are Public-dimensioned strings, and actual names of the worksheets are created in another Sub.

When I reach the line of code that uses Vlookup, I get "Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error".  Why am I getting this error?

I have used "Immediate" window to query values of Last_row_1, Last_column_1, and NCASTS (for loop counter x = 2).  All queries return valid values.

I have also used "Immediate" window to execute:

```
Worksheets(Newest_opened).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Last_row_1, Last_column_1)).Select
```

Excel shows the correct range of cells selected in the worksheet.

```
    Sub Assign_Resp_Unit_2()
    'This sub does the following:
    '
    '   - for each NCASTS in the Newest_closed worksheet:
    '       - searches in the Newest_opened worksheet for that NCASTS
    '       - if NCASTS found, gets the value from the "Responsible Unit"    column and pastes it in the same column in the Newest_closed worksheet
    '
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim NCASTS As String
    Dim Resp_Unit2 As String
    Dim Last_row_1 As Long
    Dim Last_column_1 As Long
    Dim New_opened_rng As Range
   '
   'Find range of Newest_opened worksheet
   Worksheets(Newest_opened).Activate
   Last_row_1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End  (xlUp).Row                           'get number of last row in table
   Last_column_1 = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column              'get number of last column in table
   '
   'Set the variable "Newest_opened_range" to be the Range of the Newest_opened worksheet
   Set New_opened_rng = Worksheets(Newest_opened).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Last_row_1, Last_column_1))
   '
   'search Newest_opened worksheet for Responsible Unit
   '
   'Loop through each cell in Column A of Newest_closed until a blank cell is encountered (i.e. end of entries)
   '
   Worksheets(Newest_closed).Activate
   x = 2   'initialize row counter
   Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(x, 1))
       '
       'Get NCASTS number from Column A of Newest_closed worksheet
       NCASTS = Cells(x, 1)
       '
       'Search for NCASTS number in Newest_opened worksheet and find  corresponding Responsible Unit entry;
       'Preset string variable Resp_Unit2 to "Not found" for case where NCASTS number is not in the range
       '
       Resp_Unit2 = "Not found"
       On Error Resume Next
       Resp_Unit2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(NCASTS, New_opened_rng, 11, False)
       '
       'Paste value of Resp_Unit2 to Responsible Unit column (column L) for same NCASTS in Newest_closed worksheet
       '
       Sheets(Newest_closed).Cells(x, 12).Value = Resp_Unit2
       '
       'Move to next row of Newest_closed worksheet
       '
       x = x + 1
   '
   Loop
   '
   End Sub
```

Comment: An [mcve] would help. Comment out `On Error Resume Next` for starters to see what's actually going on.

Comment: Welcome to SO. First of all, delete `On Error Resume next`, because it *hides* errors, but they still occur. Second, VLOOKUP can return an error in diferent situation. If nothing is found, it will return an error, so make sure what you are searching is on it, and it's **exactly** the same (no hidden chars, extra blanks). Secoond, make sure range `New_opened_rng` got 11 columns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to error handle 1004 Error with WorksheetFunction.VLookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18063214/11683)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `vlookup`, since you're working in a specific column out in yonder (and hoenstly ensuring it's the 11th column of the range is its own PITA (subjective, I know)), you might try `index`/`match` to ensure you're only having to specify your lookup and output ranges.  Will make a couple changes, like *ensuring to qualify ALL ranges (even the `cells` inside of `range`)*:

```
Dim OutputRng as Range, SearchRng as Range, NCASTS as String, Resp_Unit2 as String, Last_row_1 as Long
With Worksheets(Newest_opened)
    Set SearchRng = .Range(.Cells(1,1),.Cells(Last_row_1,1)) 'Assumes Column A is searched
    Set OutputRng = .Range(.Cells(1,11),.Cells(Last_row_1,11)) 'Assumes Column K has otuput
    Last_row_1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row  'qualified
    Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(x, 1)) 'qualified this, but may want to try a for or for each loop?
        NCASTS = .Cells(x, 1).Value 'qualify it, don't use .activate and added .value
        Resp_Unit2 = Application.Index(OutputRng, Application.Match(NCASTS, SearchRng, 0))
        x = x+1
    Loop
End With
```

Related to your error, you might not have an exact match, which would throw an error; using `WorkSheetFunction` you will get an error that flags, similar to the worksheet's `#VALUE`.  FoxFire touches on that in the comments section of the post which is quite important.

Comment: Hi Cyril, I tried your code, and it works as long as a match is found.  If not, it returns "Run-time error 13" - type mismatch".  I am not that familiar with error handling.  I tried modifying the code as follows: 
    On Error Resume Next
    Resp_Unit2 = Application.Index(OutputRng, Application.Match(NCASTS, SearchRng, 0))
    If IsError(Resp_Unit2) Then Resp_Unit2 = "Not found"
 However, the program still stops at the "Application.Index" step and flags the Run-time error.  Could you please advise on how to handle this error?  Thanks!

Comment: Never mind, I found a solution that works: '
    If IsError(Application.Match(NCASTS, SearchRng, 0)) Then
        Resp_Unit2 = "Not found"
    Else
        Resp_Unit2 = Application.Index(OutputRng, Application.Match(NCASTS, SearchRng, 0))
    End If
 Thanks very much for your help!