# INDEX(MATCH, MATCH) in VBA (Type 13 Type mismatch)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use an `INDEX(MATCH,MATCH)` to recreate this formula:

```
INDEX(Inflation!H$129:H$188,MATCH($J10,Inflation!$C$129:$C$188,0))
```

You may notice that the columns are not locked on the INDEX array field `Inflation!H$129:H$188`. I didn't know how to move over one column so I thought I would use an `INDEX(MATCH,MATCH)`.

With my code below I get a error 13 Type Mismatch even if I swap out `arrInflation_Bucket(I, 1)` for "EWIP", a known entry in the searched range.

```vb
Sub Costs__Repossession_Costs()
    Dim I, J, arrInflation_Bucket, arrInflation_Bucket_Label, arrNumber_of_Assets, arrQuarters, arrInflation_Label_Match, arrInflation_Quarter_Match

    arrNumber_of_Assets = Range("Costs.Number_of_Assets")
    arrQuarters = Range("Quarters_1to40")
    arrInflation_Bucket = Range("Costs.Inflation_Bucket")
    arrInflation_Bucket_Label = Range("Inflation.Inflation_Bucket_Label")

    ReDim arrCosts__Repossession_Costs(1 To UBound(arrNumber_of_Assets, 1), 1 To UBound(arrQuarters, 2))

    For I = LBound(arrInflation_Bucket, 1) To UBound(arrInflation_Bucket, 1)
        For J = LBound(arrQuarters, 2) To UBound(arrQuarters, 2)

            arrInflation_Label_Match(I, J) = Application.Match(arrInflation_Bucket(I, 1), Range("Inflation.Inflation_Bucket_Label"), 0)

            arrInflation_Quarter_Match(I, J) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(arrQuarters(1, J), Range("Quarters_1to40"), 0)

            arrCosts__Repossession_Costs(I, J) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("Inflation.Cumulative"), arrInflation_Label_Match, arrInflation_Quarter_Match)

        Next J
    Next I
End Sub
```

This is by far the most complicated formula I will need to do in VBA so if I can get this it should be all smooth sailing.

OK, I've updated the code with he instructions of the first two comments, very helpful. It is now performing the two matches correctly (used to error out on the first, but now gives me row 48 adn column 1 which is correct) but Now Type 13 errors on the INDEX().

```
    Sub Costs__Repossession_Costs()

Dim I As Long
Dim J As Long
Dim arrInflation_Bucket As Variant

Dim arrInflation_Bucket_Label, arrNumber_of_Assets, arrQuarters, arrInflation_Label_Match, arrInflation_Quarter_Match, arrInflation_Cumulative

arrNumber_of_Assets = Range("Costs.Number_of_Assets")
arrQuarters = Range("Quarters_1to40")
arrInflation_Bucket = Range("Costs.Inflation_Bucket")
arrInflation_Bucket_Label = Range("Inflation.Inflation_Bucket_Label")
arrInflation_Cumulative = Range("Inflation.Cumulative")

ReDim arrCosts__Repossession_Costs(1 To UBound(arrNumber_of_Assets, 1), 1 To UBound(arrQuarters, 2)), _
    arrInflation_Label_Match(1 To UBound(arrNumber_of_Assets, 1), 1 To UBound(arrQuarters, 2)), _
    arrInflation_Quarter_Match(1 To UBound(arrNumber_of_Assets, 1), 1 To UBound(arrQuarters, 2))

   For I = LBound(arrInflation_Bucket, 1) To UBound(arrInflation_Bucket, 1)
      For J = LBound(arrQuarters, 2) To UBound(arrQuarters, 2)

         arrInflation_Label_Match(I, J) = Application.Match(arrInflation_Bucket(I, 1), Range("Inflation.Inflation_Bucket_Label"), 0)

         arrInflation_Quarter_Match(I, J) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(arrQuarters(1, J), Range("Quarters_1to40"), 0)

         arrCosts__Repossession_Costs(I, J) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arrInflation_Cumulative, arrInflation_Label_Match, arrInflation_Quarter_Match)

      Next J
   Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: You just do `Dim x, y, z`. This will make *all* of those the `Variant` type. Instead, it's recommended that you declare each variable to be what you need them for, e.g. `Dim i as Long, j as Long, arrInflation_Bucket as Range`, etc...That will help a little bit because I'm thinking when you just call `Dim x / x = Range("A1:A10")`, it might use that *Value* and not *Range*.

Comment: You never dim `arrInflation_Label_Match` or `arrInflation_Quarter_Match` as arrays, yet you access them as arrays. The error 13 though is most likely from the fact that `Application.Match` [returns Variant/Error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064104/11683) when it does not find anything, and trying to store that in an inappropriate place results in that error.

Comment: Thanks guys, that helped move my debug along

Comment: I kept arrInflation_Bucket as VAriant because when I Dimmed as Range it gave me a Expected Array error on its redim line.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I caved like a you know what and asked my genius friend for help with this. His fantastic code is below:

```
Function firstMatchInRow(ByVal val, arr, ByVal col As Long) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(i, col) = val Then firstMatchInRow = i: Exit Function
    Next i
End Function

Sub Costs__Repossession_Costs()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, tempLabelMatch As Long
    Dim arrInflation_Bucket, arrInflation_Bucket_Label, arrNumber_of_Assets, arrQuarters, arrInflation_Cumulative, arrCosts__Repossession_Costs

    arrQuarters = Range("Quarters_1to40")
    arrInflation_Bucket = Range("Costs.Inflation_Bucket").Value
    arrInflation_Bucket_Label = Range("Inflation.Inflation_Bucket_Label").Value
    arrInflation_Cumulative = Range("Inflation.Cumulative").Value ' + add values

    ReDim arrCosts__Repossession_Costs(1 To UBound(arrInflation_Cumulative, 1), 1 To UBound(arrQuarters, 2))

       For i = LBound(arrInflation_Bucket, 1) To UBound(arrInflation_Bucket, 1)
            tempLabelMatch = firstMatchInRow(arrInflation_Bucket(i, 1), arrInflation_Bucket_Label, 1)
            For j = LBound(arrInflation_Cumulative, 2) To UBound(arrInflation_Cumulative, 2)
                arrCosts__Repossession_Costs(i, j) = arrInflation_Cumulative(tempLabelMatch, j)
            Next j
       Next i
End Sub
```