# Application.WorksheetFunction vs. WorksheetFunction

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

This one is a rather short question and probably easy to answer, however I fail to do so myself at this point:

---

<sub>**Sample data:**</sub>

```
A
B
C
```

---

<sub>**Sample code:**</sub>

```
With Sheet1
    Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("D", .Columns(1), 0)    'Option1
    Debug.Print Application.Match("D", .Columns(1), 0)                      'Option2
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Match("D", .Columns(1), 0)                'Option3
End With
```

---

<sub>**Question:**</sub>

I know that option2 lost intellisense and will not go into debug mode, however option1 and option3 behave the same

- Intellisense works
- Error is thrown and code goes into debug-mode

Whereas documentation on the `WorksheetFunction` object [says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction) that we can use the `WorksheetFunction` property of the `Application` object, it seems to work just fine without doing so.

So, what is the added value to use `Application` object reference in this regard and what is the disadvantage of leaving it out?

Comment: I'd say that `Application` is global context and when we use anything, that compiler can't find in its current context, it looks it in `Application`, eventually finding `Application.WorksheetFunction` in your case. So both should be equivalent. (this is how it works in JavaScript) BUT I might be wrong.

Comment: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application(object)) states, that some functions and properties can be called without `Application.`, so it is true that `Application.WorksheetFunction` is equivalent to `WorksheetFunction`, but it is false, that `Application` server as global context.

Comment: In option 1, the object reference is explicitly set whereas in option 3, it is implicit.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn, right so it appears that the `WorksheetFunction` object is part of this "most common user-interface objects" and therefor doesn't need the `Application` object qualifier. Correct? (despite `WorksheetFunction` being a property of the `Application` object)

Comment: It can be thought of like that, definietely. I don't know what were intentions of developers of VBA, but they allowed to use some functions and properties of `Application` "on their own", and make `Application` implicit.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn, if you care to answer below I'll mark it as answered to close the thread. It appears there is no advantage of leaving in the `Application` object qualifier when using `WorksheetFunction`. It might still be good practice to leave it in though.

Comment: There is no difference between `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` and `WorksheetFunction.Match` (because there is no difference between `Application.WorksheetFunction` and `WorksheetFunction`). However, [there is a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064104/11683) between `Application.Match` and the other two.

Comment: @GSerg, nice routing to that older thread. I knew about the difference but just chucked the option in to show that the other two are alike.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say that `Application` is global context and when we use anything, that compiler can't find in its current context, it looks it in `Application`, eventually finding `Application.WorksheetFunction` in your case. So both should be equivalent. (this is how it works in JavaScript) BUT I might be wrong.

**UPDATE**

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application(object)) states, that some functions and properties can be called without Application., so it is true that Application.WorksheetFunction is equivalent to WorksheetFunction, but it is false, that Application serves as global context.

**UPDATE**

[According to this interesing article](https://www.excelanytime.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=180:excel-vba-application-object-the-default-object-in-excel&catid=79&Itemid=475), `Application` is default object indeed:

> The Application object is the Default Object, Excel assumes it even when it is not specified.

Comment: That is a very interesting article, thanks for thinking along. Coding within the Excel app does not require `Application` as it is set as its "explicit" default anyway. Good to know =)

Comment: Those members of `Application` object that do not need explicit use of `Application` are in fact in hidden `Global` class. It can be [viewed](https://i.imgur.com/1SB2yoU.png) in Object Browser but requires checking `Show hidden members` first