# "Subscript out of range" on array converted from Range

Tags: excel, vba

I saw quite a number of questions/answers along these lines, but after reading a bunch of them, I'm still confused. I'm sorry if this is the nᵗʰ time a variant of this has been asked.

I can't figure out why this code dies on line 5 with a "subscript out of range" error in VBA (Excel for Mac v16.38):

```
Public Function array_test()
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim array_slice As Variant
    arr = Range("TestData!B27:F32").Value2
    array_slice = arr(2)  'dies here with error 9
    array_test = array_slice
End Function
```

Looking at the values pane, arr is clearly a Variant/Variant(1 to 6, 1 to 5) with all the expected data. There is nothing special about the cells, just non-formula data.

Even if I change the declarations to arr() and array_slice() or remove ".Value2", I get the same results. Even trying Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, 2) rather than arr(2) gets me nowhere.

What am I missing?

P.S. I'm a C/Python programmer normally, so I'm thinking of arrays in those terms.

Comment: If you want to access an element from a 2D-array, you'd need to access it as such too e.g.: `array_slice = arr(2,1)`

Comment: I don't. I want to return the whole array for processing at a higher level.

Comment: What is it you need sliced from the 2D-array then? A whole specific column?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do an array slice. A specific row in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually one would loop an 2D-array for it's elements, however, since you specifically mentioned you would like to slice it through VBA, you could use `Application.Index`. For example try:

```
array_slice = Application.Index(arr, 2, 0) 'Slice 2nd row into 1D-array.
```

The idea here is to feed `Application.Index` with a static '2' which represents the row of interest. In the same fashion you could slice a specific column of interest, though if you need this to be an 1D-array, you'd need to use `Application.Transpose`, however there are limitations to this method:

```
With Application
    array_slice = .Transpose(.Index(arr, 0, 2)) 'Slice 2nd column into 1D-array.
End With
```

Comment: I had originally started using Index because, according to the docs, if I feed it a 0 for the column, it returns the whole row. I have done this before and it works like a charm. In this case it wasn't working, so I started monkeying with things like arr(2). I noticed that you used Application.Index not Application.WorksheetFunction.Index. I tried using Application.Index(arr, 2,0) and it works. For some reason.

Comment: The funny thing is, Application.Index does not appear in the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application(object)) but works. It may be passing through to WorksheetFunction.Index, but I wonder why the different behavior? Also, with a 0 array_slice becomes a Variant(1 to 5). With your previous Evaluate idea it becomes a Variant(1 to 5, 1 to 1). In any case, thanks.

Comment: @nrb, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59212996/9758194) will clarify some things for you on `Application` vs. `WorksheetFunction`? Both work fine for me. Glad it helped you out =)

Answer (score 0):

When you copy data from a Range and the Range contains more than one cell, you get n 2-dimensional array in any case (even if you have only one row or one column).

To access a single value from that array, you have to provide both indices, like `arr(2, 1)`. However, if you want to get a *one*-dimensional array, containing all values from a *row* (first index) or a *column* (second index), you need to create that array by your own - there is no `slice` function in VBA. You can dimension an array at runtime using the `ReDim`-command:

```
Dim array_slice(), i As Long
ReDim array_slice(LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1))
For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    array_slice(i) = arr(i, 2)
Next i
```

To get the values of a column, use

```
Dim array_slice(), i As Long
ReDim array_slice(LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2))
For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
    array_slice(i) = arr(2, i)
Next i
```