# How to apply vlookup with on error value 0 and resume

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, onerror

I am using vlookup range to apply formula in last empty column.
its working fine but if error is there it's showing blank cell, Well,I dont mind that but,
when the formula is applied again in next column the value is shifted to previous column's blank cell, as one of the cell in previous column was blank due to error.

So I need it to give value 0 or "error" instead of blank.

```
Sub GET_BHAV()

    Dim OpenWs As Worksheet, bhavWs As Worksheet
    Dim OpenLastRow As Long, bhavLastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim bhavRng As Range

    Set OpenWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Open")

    Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\playt\Desktop\STACK\VANGU\cm07JAN2020bhav.csv"

    Set bhavWs = Workbooks("cm07JAN2020bhav.csv").Worksheets("cm07JAN2020bhav")

    bhavLastRow = bhavWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    OpenLastRow = OpenWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set bhavRng = bhavWs.Range("A2:G" & bhavLastRow)

    For x = 2 To OpenLastRow
        On Error Resume Next
        OpenWs.Cells(x, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
                                                                          OpenWs.Range("A" & x).Value, bhavRng, 3, Flase)
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to change this `On Error Resume Next` to handle the error.  Or check the existence of the value before doing the `vlookup`  `Countif` >0  for example

Comment: i tried but, no luck.can you write in code?

Comment: Add the code you tried then, we can see what you've done so far then.  I think @shai has done it for you.  Google's results would have helped.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063214/how-to-error-handle-1004-error-with-worksheetfunction-vlookup  It's better to learn these things rather than copy code verbatim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trap (handle) the `VLOOKUP` error, in case it doesn't find a match.

Try the code below of the `VLOOKUP` section:

```
' define a new variable
Dim VlookUpVal As Variant

With OpenWs ' Using With statement
    For x = 2 To OpenLastRow
        ' read the value of VLOOKUP to variant
        VlookUpVal = Application.VLookup(.Range("A" & x).Value, bhavRng, 3, False)

        ' check if VLOOKUP returned an Error
        If IsError(VlookUpVal) Then
            .Cells(x, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = 0
        Else
            .Cells(x, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = VlookUpVal
        End If
    Next x
End With
```

Comment: one more question.
I have 2 sheets "Open" and "sheet2", these codes apply vlookup formula from row 2 to end of range in last empty column of the sheet "Open".
The first row in the sheet "Open has dates, is it possible to apply formula in the column of respective date which matches date in Sheet1 cell A1??
pls reply

Comment: @nitinthakur you should create a new post, with the modified code, and I (and others) can look at it and help. You should add a screen-shot of your data, so it will be easier for others to understand

Comment: I inserted new post, can you check now?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60080041/define-vlookup-result-column-by-changing-date-in-specified-cell