# Define Vlookup result column by changing date in specified cell

Tags: excel, vba, lookup

This is about my Result/Target workbook, I have 2 sheets "Open" and "sheet2", these codes apply vlookup formula from row 2 to end of range in last available empty column of the sheet "Open". The entire first row in the sheet "Open has dates, is it possible to apply formula to the column of respective date which matches date in Sheet2 cell "A1" instead of last empty column??

Sub GET_BHAV()

```
Dim VlookUpVal As Variant
Dim OpenWs As Worksheet, HighWs As Worksheet, bhavWs As Worksheet
Dim OpenLastRow As Long, bhavLastRow As Long, x As Long
Dim bhavRng As Range


Set OpenWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Open")
Set HighWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("High")
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\playt\Desktop\STACK\VANGU\cm07JAN2020bhav.csv"
Set bhavWs = Workbooks("cm07JAN2020bhav.csv").Worksheets("cm07JAN2020bhav")
bhavLastRow = bhavWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
OpenLastRow = OpenWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
HighLastRow = HighWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set bhavRng = bhavWs.Range("A2:G" & bhavLastRow)
With OpenWs
    For x = 2 To OpenLastRow
        'On Error Resume Next
        VlookUpVal = Application.VLookup(.Range("A" & x).Value, bhavRng, 3, False)
        'gives #NA value to cell with error
        If IsError(VlookUpVal) Then
            .Cells(x, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = "#NA"
            ' highlights cell color on error
            .Cells(x, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Else
            .Cells(x, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = VlookUpVal
        End If
    Next x
    With HighWs
        For x = 2 To HighLastRow
            VlookUpVal = Application.VLookup(.Range("A" & x).Value, bhavRng, 4, False)
            If IsError(VlookUpVal) Then
                .Cells(x, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = "#NA"
            Else
                .Cells(x, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = VlookUpVal
            End If
        Next x
    End With
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Files have already been attached

Comment: yes i can fix that too

Comment: can you upload a screen-shot of your data ?

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/ITjFsqC.jpg

Comment: I uploaded screenshot the formula is applicable to last empty column i.e"GY"
but, i need to use the formula to the respective date's column. suppose I put the date value in  sheet1 Cell"A1" 13-01-20 then the lookup value must be pasted to column "HC" having date 13-01-20

Comment: Of course, it is possible. Looking at the problem and the amount and complexity of the code, I assume it is hasn't been written by you, am I right? Nevertheless, what did you try to change or how and what is exactly your problem (at what step of implementing the solution you don't know what to do)? What I would basically do would be finding the column index of the appropriate column and passing that into the methods in your code (so change it as little as possible). Can you write code to find the column of the header with the date written in A1 cell in the appropriate sheet?

Comment: I tried but no luck