# Getting a filename from a dialog

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to read XML file and modify dates in XML using an another excel file and do a vlookup on to this excel file. After overwriting date, I am saving XML File.

But I am getting **Error MisMatch Type 13 error** when opening Excel File. I have played dim types but nothing seems to be working. Can someone help?

Here is the code:

```vb
Function GetFile() As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'**Open XML'**

    Dim XML_in As Variant
    XML_in = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="XML (*.XML), *.XML", Title:="Select XML Order List")
    If XML_in = False Then Exit Sub
    GetFile = XML_in
    Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0") 
    XMLFileName = XML_in 'XML IN Filename'
    Debug.Print XML_in

'**Manipulate oXML'**

    oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName) 'Read XML'
    Set xmlGroup = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/ppr:pprdata/ppr:Group") 'Navigate to ppr:Group'
    Set xmlOrderLists = xmlGroup(1) 'Navigate to <ppr:Group name="Order lists">'
    Set xmlProdPgm = xmlOrderLists.SelectNodes("ppr:ProductionProgram")
    Set xmlFirmOrders = xmlProdPgm(0).ChildNodes

'**Open AMS File'**

    Dim src As Variant '
    Set src = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Open AMS File")
    If src = False Then Exit Sub
    'Workbooks.Open("AMS Schedule example.xlsx", True, True)
    Set Sheet = src.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ran = Sheet.range("A1:B9")

    For i = 1 To xmlFirmOrders. Length - 1 
        Debug.Print xmlFirmOrders(i).Attributes.getNamedItem("ppr:id").Value
        Set xmlNumber = xmlFirmOrders(i).SelectSingleNode("ppr:number")
        Set xmlStartTime = xmlFirmOrders(i).SelectSingleNode("ppr:startTime")
        xmlStartTime.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup(xmlNumber, ran, 2, 0), "NOTFOUND") 'Update ppr:Starttime'
    Next i

'**Close AMS File**

    src.Close False
    Set src = Nothing

'**Save XML'**

    Dim XML_out As Variant
    XML_out = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="XML (*.XML), *.XML", Title:="Output XML File for Avix")
    If XML_out = False Then Exit Sub
    GetFile = XML_out
    oXMLFile.Save XML_out
    Debug.Print XML_out

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

Comment: `Set src = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Open AMS File")` should not have a `Set`, and you need to actually open the workbook after getting the filename.

Comment: thanks it worked. Now it creates Run-time error '424' Object required on the line
**Set Sheet = src.Worksheets("Sheet1")**

Comment: Did you actually open `src`? `Dim wb as Workbook`, `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(src)`, then `Set Sheet = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")`.

Comment: I did that now. It generated Run-time Error 1004 **Set wb = Workbooks.Open(src)**

Comment: It is giving error at the _ xmlStartTime.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup(xmlNumber, ran, 2, 0), "NOTFOUND")_ . Error says 1004 Unable to get the Vlookup property of the worksheet function class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064104/9245853

Comment: I tired this but it is giving same error. Looks like Application.vlookup does not work. If i use this, it says Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error.

Comment: Read that answer a *bit more carefully* and implement all of it, including `IsError`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following code. First get the FileName as string, that use the Workbooks.Open to open the file.

```
 Dim src As String
 Dim wb As Workbook
 src = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Open AMS File")
 Set wb = Workbooks.Open(src)
```