# Vlookup fails because value is missing

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, vlookup

I need to figure out a way to deal with runtime error 1004 for vba vlookup functions.

For some rows Vlookup cannot find the value in the table because the value does not exist. In these cases the sub procedure stops/fails completely and I get an error message. This is bad.
How can i tell Excel to skip those rows when the value is missing in the table and continue with the sub procedure?

Many thanks!

```
Sub Vlookup()
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Set myrange = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("D:E")
For i = 2 To LastRow
Cells(i, 5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Cells(i, 3), myrange, 2, False)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: The linked duplicate should have all you need.

Comment: ...but the best answer is not the accepted one.

Comment: Definitely agree with @TimWilliams - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064104/9245853) is the best one.