# VBA Vlookup errors

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have written vlookups plenty of times but dont have any of my old code examples to hand and I know I am missing something really simple here.

Context - I am creating a code workbook separate from the file to work on. I have  created a function that creates an order ID and during that process I have to lookup a value and swop it for the value of the look up. I am absolutely certain I am simply not getting the syntax right for the sheet referencing part of the lookup but despite checking various posts on here and changing it several times I cannot get it right

```
 Function build_order_ID(building_name As String, customer_name As String, order_number As Integer)
Dim building_name_new As String

building_name_new = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(building_name, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("building_ref").Range("A1:B5"), 2, False).Value

build_order_ID = building_name & "-" & order_number & "-" & customer_name

End Function
```

The sheet is sheet3 but named building_ref

I am using this code to generate the output but it always stops during the lookup normally with object errors but I did get different errors when changing the format of calling the sheet

```
Public Sub test_order_ID()

Dim order_ID As String

order_ID = build_order_ID("testvalue", "Jack", 1)
MsgBox order_ID
End Sub
```

Comment: "I am creating a code workbook separate from the file to work on" - so then I'm not sure you want to use `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: Sorry poor English. The lookup file is in the code workbook. I was trying to say that so people understood There would be other workbooks in the mix so I have to be explicit in the lookup as the active workbook when the code itself runs will be a different one to what the code references. With the way the code is right now it is code 424 object error which is why I am fixed on the sheet referencing from the relatively little experience I have had

Comment: Remove the `.Value`.

Comment: You may also want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063214/how-to-error-handle-1004-error-with-worksheetfunction-vlookup).

Comment: Annoyingly, i added that after changing it a few times as i read a post suggesting to set the variable you need to call out you want the value although thinking about it vlookup naturally outputs a value. That did indeed solve it. Thank you

Comment: Would highly suggest switching to `Application.Vlookup` as the link I mentioned suggests.

Comment: I have adjusted that as well. Thank you, If you post the answer I can properly accredit you for your assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben who pointed out my error with the .value at the end of the vlookup. After removal the code executed correctly