# VBA vlookup - Number column issue

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Below is the code snippet I am using for vlookup. arg & arg2 are stored in number which is not working with below function. Can someone please guide me with solution on this?

```
Results = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(arg1, arg2, arg3, "False")
    
MyErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
```

Comment: Arg1 needs to be a value or cell reference, arg2 needs to be two or more columns. arg3 needs to be a column index number relative to the columns supplied in arg2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.vlookup

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063214/how-to-error-handle-1004-error-with-worksheetfunction-vlookup

Comment: Side note: for the last argument, use `0`, or `False` *without* quotes.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen for inputs. Yes, I tried changing last parameter to False or 0 but same issue. Just to share more insights of what I m doing, Arg1 is a value which I am iterating from a column and searching up against range -arg2 in separate sheet with Arg3 as 1.

Comment: Switch to `Application.Vlookup` as covered in the linked question.

Comment: @BigBen, I tried Application.Vlookup but it impacted the lookup for text type as well and not rendering any result. Also, Application.Vlookup does not show up in Auto fill also

Comment: `Application.Vlookup` is the late-bound version of `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup`, so yes, it will not have Intellisense... but, you still should use it.