# Vlookup error number 1004 when name not found in the search range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to find the skill match with the name. I know that there are some names in my Data sheet which are not in my Skills sheet (I do not have their skills).

I get error 1004 when it comes to the names that are not in the Skills sheet.

For example I have the following name in the data sheet:

```
ASS
bbb
zzz
MMM
DDDD
```

and the following skills for them in the Skills sheets

```
ASS: 1_Level
bbb: 2_lvel
zzz: 3_Level
MMM:  OM
```

When I run the code I get the error when it wants to find the skill of DDDD.

While I use IsError I would like to have "Not find" for this case in data sheet.

Why is this error happening?

```
Dim Skill As String
Dim Skill2 As String
Dim Name As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Set WB = ThisWorkbook

LastRow = WB.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Set rng = WB.Worksheets("skills").Range("A:B")

For i=2 To LastRow

    Name = WB.Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 9)

    Skill = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLOOKUP(Name, rng, 2, False)

    If Not IsError(Skill) Then
        Skill2 = Skill
    Else
        Skill = "Not find"
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to error handle 1004 Error with WorksheetFunction.VLookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063214/how-to-error-handle-1004-error-with-worksheetfunction-vlookup)

Comment: Use `Application.Vlookup` - drop the `WorksheetFunction`.

Comment: I have tried the once in the Link it did not help. I have already the same error.

Comment: You're saying you get an error even if you use `Application.Vlookup`?

Comment: yes i get erorr 13 with Application.vlookup.

Comment: `Dim Skill As Variant`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064104/9245853) in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing of

```
Skill = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLOOKUP(Name, rng, 2, False)

If Not IsError(Skill) Then

Skill2 = Skill

Else

Skill = "Not find"

End If
```

with

```
If WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Application.VLOOKUP(Name, rng, 2, False)) then
   Skill = "Not find"' Skill or Skill2 = ...?
Else
   Skill2 = Skill
End if
```

Comment: @P.B: Try the updated code. I took your code line as it was and only tried to catch the error. It should be `Application.Vlookup` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup`

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I have changed the Skill from String with Variant and used the Application.Vlookup. Now it is working very well.

Comment: @P.B: What kind of data type are you expecting `Vlookup` to return?