# VBA for Excel IsNA

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a VBA Macro which detects the VLOOKUP field IsNA or not, but I found that it is not work when really the Vlookup formula is returned #N/A.

My code is below:

```
Private Function searchPJCode(item As String) As String
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Worksheets("Project").Range("A1:C1000")
If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Left(Right(item, 3), 2), myRange, 3, 0)) = False Then
    searchPJCode = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Left(Right(item, 3), 2), myRange, 3, 0)
Else
    If Left(Right(item, 4), 3) = "--0" Or Right(item, 4) = "--11" Then
        searchPJCode = "ZRSC"
    Else
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Left(item, 3), myRange, 3, 0)) = False Then
            searchPJCode = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Left(item, 3), myRange, 3, 0)
        Else
            searchPJCode = "OTHERS"
        End If
    End If
End If
End Function
```

I hope here have advanced skilled guys can help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. You've simply repeated the information already available in the tags and added IsNA. Your title should be clear enough to be of use to a future site user who is scanning through a list of search results trying to find a problem solution. Your current title contains nothing that would be of use to them.

Comment: See the linked duplicate, but look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064104/9245853), which is better than the accepted one. Use `Application.Vlookup` and `IsError` to test if the result is an error.