# VBA Vlookup missmatch. (Run-time error 13)

Tags: excel, vba

In a for-loop after 50+ iterations I get the error With Vlookup in VBA.

[image]

And when debugging:

[image]

I tried to add the `CStr()` in the lookup value argument, but that did not help.

Range `DB` in the sheet:

[image]

Is it the two leading zeros that it cannot recognize in the table?

However, I have another case where the strings begins with letters and i still get the error. It seems so random, in a loop 3/74 rows give this error. I have verified that the values do exists in the `DB` range  (but that should not be the problem either, because when looking up something random, it does not give a rune-time error, but the result-handle from vlookup contain the error.)

Comment: What did you `Dim s_OA` as ? Should be a `Variant`, because `Application.Vlookup` will return an error value if the vlookup doesn't find a match.

Comment: @BigBen As String, should i have it as variant?

Comment: Yes... you need to test if it's an error with `IsError`.... https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064104/9245853

Comment: Yes, Now `s_OA` gets the value `Error2042`

Comment: Are the values in the `DB` range *numbers* or *text-that-look-like-numbers*?

Comment: I did not have `CStr` at first, but I added it when this error occurred, to test if it would help

Comment: Most of the values in `DB` have the `General` formatting. The cases where there is 2 leading zeros to a number, then the cell is formatted as in the picture in my original post

Comment: Then it seems like the underlying values are numbers, not text, so you shouldn't be looking up a `String` but rather a numeric value.

Comment: One could think that, but as I wrote in my original question. I also get this same error with a string that starts with letters.

Comment: The original error is because as noted `s_OA` should be a `Variant`... the question of whether or not the vlookup finds anything is separate, and that is totally dependent on how you're getting `s_matNumber` and what the underlying data in `DB` *actually* is (not just its format). The format a value takes and the actual value are two separate things. In any case, you need error handling as demonstrated in the linked answer.

Comment: I now set the cell value to `="006880776"` (i.e. a cell in range `DB`). Then Vba vlookup returns `Empty` instead of the previous `Error2042`, although the lookup argument is a string. Error handling in the provided link does not help my problem.

Comment: Good - that means the Vlookup succeeded. You really have/had *two* problems. The first was fixed by using `Variant`. The second, you're still working on. Note that the *text* "006880776" is **not** the same as the number 6880776 formatted to add two leading zeros.

Comment: oh, I just now realized that column 4 in `DB` actually was empty :D (unlike the other rows)

Comment: Thank you for the help. @BigBen