# How to compare HLookup result to ""?

Tags: excel, vba

I tried using Hlookup.

The code returns the following error:

> “Unable to get the HLookup property of the WorksheetFunction Class”

I tried error handling but I get:

> Run-time error '13' Type mismatch.

I realised it is because of conflicting data types. How do I express `If myHLookupResult <> "" Then MsgBox myHLookupResult` in a way it can handle looking at the long datatype.

```vb
Dim myHLookupResult As Long

On Error Resume Next
myHLookupResult = WorksheetFunction.HLookup(CalcSheet.Range("C81"), CalcSheet, 57)
On Error GoTo 0
                        
If myHLookupResult <> "" Then MsgBox myHLookupResult
                        
pmp.Offset(0, 14).Value = myHLookupResult
```

Comment: You can't compare a `Long` to a blank string. Here it's probably easier to use a `Variant` and  `Application.HLookup`, and then `IsError` to check. Use the same approach as the VLookup approach demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064104/9245853).

Answer (score 0):

Illustrating @BigBen's comment, and reviewing your code:

- Use a variant type so you can handle the returned error
- Use variables to set the lookup variable and range (not required)
- Define if you want an exact match or not with the last argument in the lookup function

Side note: You lookup range was set to the name of the sheet (or at least it appears)

Read code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs.

```
Public Sub HLookupResult()
    
    ' Not required, but nice to set the value to a variable
    Dim lookupValue As Variant
    lookupValue = CalcSheet.Range("C81").Value
    
    ' Not required, but nice to set the lookup range to a variable
    Dim lookupRange As Range
    Set lookupRange = CalcSheet.Range("A1:B5")
    
    ' Use variant so if not found can handle the error
    Dim resultValue As Variant
    resultValue = Application.HLookup(lookupValue, lookupRange, 2, False)
    
    ' Check the error and do something
    If IsError(resultValue) Then
        MsgBox "Not found"
    Else
        MsgBox resultValue
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there, 
Thanks for the help - I've made the following tweaks:

```
Dim myHLookupResult As Variant

myHLookupResult = WorksheetFunction.HLookup(CalcSheet.Range("C81"), CalcSheet, 57)
                        If IsError(myHLookupResult) Then
                            MsgBox "no match"
                        Else
                            pmp.Offset(0, 14).Value = myHLookupResult
                        
                        End If
```

although I still get the initial error now of “Unable to get the HLookup property of the WorksheetFunction Class”

Comment: As to your side note, I thought I put the whole sheet to look up, and for it to look at row 57 for the same value in C81 of the same sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I realised I didn't know how to use the HLookup function and needed it to be:

```
myHLookupResult = WorksheetFunction.HLookup(CalcSheet.Range("C81"), CalcSheet.Range("C57:CX58"), 2)
```

Although I'm sure the error checking will help if any issues were to arise.

Thanks.