# VBA Return Application.Sumifs answer in a variable

Tags: vba, function, variables

Is it possible to store the answer of a function, written as follows, in a variable?

```
'--------------------
'This is part of a somewhat bigger code so some variables has been declared again
'--------------------

Sub afletteren()

Dim vAfletteren         As Boolean
Dim OutWb               As Workbook
Dim OutFileStatus       As Range
Dim OutFileHeader       As Range
Dim Key1                As Variant
Dim Key2                As Variant
Dim OutFileKPL          As Range
Dim OutFileGBR          As Range
Dim OutFileBedrag       As Range
Dim OutFileStatistieknr As Range
Dim OutFileVouchernr    As Range

vAfletteren = True
Set OutWb = ActiveWorkbook
Set OutFileHeader = Range("D5")

If vAfletteren = True Then

With OutWb.Sheets("Dump")
Set OutFileKPL = .Cells(OutFileHeader.Row, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="KPL", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
Set OutFileGBR = .Cells(OutFileHeader.Row, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="Rekeningnummer", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
Set OutFileBedrag = .Cells(OutFileHeader.Row, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="BedragPrimair", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
Set OutFileStatistieknr = .Cells(OutFileHeader.Row, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="Statistieknummer1", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
Set OutFileVouchernr = .Cells(OutFileHeader.Row, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="FactVerplNr", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
Set OutFileStatus = .Cells(OutFileHeader.Row, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="Status", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
End With

'Whenever key1 = 0 then set the "Status" to "Afletteren", the first row of this example equals to 0 so after running this code, the outcome has to be "Afletteren" in the first cell of the status column
S = OutFileHeader.Row + 1

With OutWb.Sheets("Dump")
For T = OutFileHeader.Row + 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If .Cells(S, OutFileStatus.Column).Value <> "Afletteren" Then
         Key1 = Application.SumIfs(OutFileBedrag.EntireColumn.Address, OutFileKPL.EntireColumn.Address, .Range(Split(Cells(1, OutFileKPL.Column).Address, "$")(1) & S).Value, OutFileGBR.EntireColumn.Address, .Range(Split(Cells(1, OutFileGBR.Column).Address, "$")(1) & S).Value, OutFileVouchernr.EntireColumn.Address, .Range(Split(Cells(1, OutFileVouchernr.Column).Address, "$")(1) & S).Value)
        'Key1 = Application.SumIfs(sumrange                          , Range 1                        , Criteria 1                                                          , Range 2                        , Criteria 2                                                          , Range 3                              , Criteria 3
            
'Check
MsgBox "Application.SumIfs(" & OutFileBedrag.EntireColumn.Address & ", " & OutFileKPL.EntireColumn.Address & ", " & .Range(Split(Cells(1, OutFileKPL.Column).Address, "$")(1) & S).Value & ", " & OutFileGBR.EntireColumn.Address & ", " & .Range(Split(Cells(1, OutFileGBR.Column).Address, "$")(1) & S).Value & ", " & OutFileVouchernr.EntireColumn.Address & ", " & .Range(Split(Cells(1, OutFileVouchernr.Column).Address, "$")(1) & S).Value & ")"
MsgBox Key1         'has to be equal to 0

            If Key1 = 0 Then
            .Cells(S, OutFileStatus.Column).Value = "Afletteren"
            End If
    End If
    S = S + 1
Next T
End With

End If

Exit Sub

ERROR_HANDLING:
MsgBox "Error Handling = " & vStatus

End Sub
```

Whenever i run this piece of code, it will return with a type-error on the msgbox line. is it possible to store the answer of the function in a variable instead of in a predefined range? i want to continue whenever the Sumifs function returns a value of 0.

i hope to hear from someone.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Yes, you can store a worksheet function result in a variable instead of a sheet cell. Your problem is most likely that `SumIfs` [returns an error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064104/11683) which cannot be displayed with MsgBox.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible, here is a code sample:

```
Sub StackOverflow()

Dim Key1 As Variant

Key1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("B1:B6"), Range("A1:A6"), Range("A1"))
MsgBox Key1

End Sub
```

Obviously you need to adjust ranges (you can use variables, I just inserted fixed range). 
Messagebox shows numeric result.

Comment: thanks @Hronic for the quick answer. i've not yet find the solution so i've changed the code above to a somewhat bigger one to possible specify the problem. The error occurs somewhat at the end of the code. The first msgbox shows the following formula: Application.Sumifs($H:$H, $B:$B, 1, $F:$F, 100, $M:$M, 0), the second msgbox gives an error. The answer to the formula whenever i would use it in the sheet itself, result in a 0. can you determine what goes wrong?

Comment: && i want to post an example file but i think that is not possible. if there is a way and it's needed, please enlighten me how to

Comment: could you put a file on a google drive?
I will take a look at it