# My Range on Vlookup source worksheet says Nothing

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

This code line says = Nothing?
Set SrcDataRange = Src.Range("A13:P" & LastRow)

It`s in a Vlookup code shown below.
If there is a simpler way to write a Vlookup code please tell me?
I used the same code as before but different workbooks and it worked??

```
 Private Sub Up_Date_Prices_Click()



  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim SrcOpen As Workbook
    Dim Des As Workbook
    Dim JCM As Worksheet
    Dim Src As Worksheet
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim PLDataRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    FilePath = "\\TGS-SRV01\Share\ShopFloor\PRODUCTION\PURCHASING\"
    Filename = "TGS Group Inventory Sheet - Main.xlsx"

   
  
    Set SrcOpen = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & Filename)
    Set Src = SrcOpen.Worksheets("Part List")
    LastRow = Src.Cells(Src.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    Set SrcDataRange = Src.Range("A13:P" & LastRow)
    Windows("TGS Group Inventory Sheet - Main.xlsx").Visible = True
   
    Set Des = Workbooks("Automated Cardworker.xlsm")
    Set JCM = Des.Worksheets("Job Card Master")


    JCM.Range("O15").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(JCM.Range("D15"), SrcDataRange, 16, 0)

  
  
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  
   SrcOpen.Close
  
  
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True


      End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This row I think is wrong

```
LastRow = Src.Cells(PL.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
```

`PL` is not set anywhere. Also the variable `PLDataRange` is never used. I guess you intend to set that somewhere?

I have `Option Explicit` turned on as default and it means you can never use undeclared variables

Let me know if this is helpful, thanks

Comment: Sorry the PL should have been Src. It`s Src on my code now but still, it can`t find the range?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is answered here [How to error handle 1004 Error with WorksheetFunction.VLookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063214/how-to-error-handle-1004-error-with-worksheetfunction-vlookup)

In summary, if there is no match VLookup throws an error - if it is not this then check your last row: `O15` your output is only 2 rows below `A13` the first anchor to your input range so check that column`P` doesnt extend below row 14.

Some observations, `JCM.Range("D15")` might be better as `JCM.Range("D15").value` and also the final parameter is actually a boolean so might be better as `False` rather than zero. They may or may not have any effects here but it may be helpful to get into that habit: Little mistakes like these have cost me hours debugging in the past :)

Comment: It`s not error 1004. Also, I am being silly because the input range should a column of figures from Range O13 to O299 on the destination Sheet.