# Using a VLOOKUP in a user defined function

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, vlookup

I am trying to set up a user defined function that takes the value from a cell and then validates, if that value is also in a range of values on a different sheet. It could be on two different sheets, which one to look at depends on the value of another cell, the 'scope'.

I have set up the following so far:

```
Function reviewFun(input As Range, scope As Range)

    If scope.Value = "AAA" Then
        If IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(input.Value, Sheet3.Range("B:B"), 1, 0)) Then
            reviewFun = "PLEASE CHECK"
        Else
            reviewFun = "FINE"
        End If
    Else
        If IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(input.Value, Sheet4.Range("B:B"), 1, 0)) Then
            reviewFun = "PLEASE CHECK"
        Else
            reviewFun = "ALSO FINE"
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

However, if the input value is on the other sheets, it returns just #VALUE! instead of "PLEASE CHECK". How can I fix it? Could I do it without the VLOOKUP?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**

Dropping the `.WorksheetFunction` solved the problem, thank you!

However, I also have the issue, that if one of the values in `input` or the lookup range is a number, it also returns an error.

Is there a way in VBA to pass something as a string? I tried the below but it does not work.

`IsError(Application.Match(input.Text, Sheet3.Range("B:B").Text, 0))`

Comment: Use `Application.VLookup`, drop the `WorksheetFunction`. Note that you could just use `Match` or `CountIf` here as well.

Comment: @BigBen - if i understand correctly your suggestion works because of late/early binding? Can you provide a reference or explanation? I'd like to understand why one works and the other doesnt - thanks

Comment: @JohnnieL- check out [this recent article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2021/02/15/worksheetfunction-and-errors/) from Mathieu Guindon. Or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064104/9245853).

Comment: `Match` or `VLookup` should work with numbers. What is a sample number that's not working?

Comment: It is 168926103 in this instance, but I think the problem is that on one sheet it is formatted as a number and on the other it is not.

Comment: If you want to debug a UDF which is returning #VALUE then the easiest way is to call it from a Sub with the "problem" arguments

Comment: What's the Excel version you are using?

Comment: As per your last attempt _`IsError(Application.Match(input.Text, Sheet3.Range("B:B").Text, 0))`_, it seems that you would like to have not only the `input`, but also the _"lookup ranges"_ (i.e. `Sheet3.Range("B:B")` and `Sheet4.Range("B:B")`) as `string`. Please confirm.

Comment: Correct, both need to be strings (at least I hope that would solve the problem)

Answer (score 0):

**Requirements:**

To set up an user defined function that validates if a given `cell.value` (Input) is present *(either as number or string)* in a predefined `range` identified by a `cell.value` (Scope). Returns a string.

**Syntax:**
*Match_ƒLookup(rInput As Range, rScope As Range) As String*

If `rInput` or `rScope` are a multi-cell range, the function will use the value of the range 1st cell converted as string.

In order to ensure all numbers are compared as strings, the function uses this formula to convert the range as an array of string:

```
=TRIM('#WSH'!#RNG)
```

where:

- `#WSH` = `Worksheet.Name`
- `#RNG` = `Range.Address`

**UDF:**

```
Function Match_ƒLookup(rInput As Range, rScope As Range) As String
Const kFml As String = "=TRIM('#WSH'!#RNG)"         'Formula to return Lookup Range as an Array of Strings
Dim sReturn As String                               'Function result
Dim sInput As String                                'Input converted to string
Dim aLookup As Variant                              'Lookup Array
Dim sFml As String                                  'Customized Formula
    
    sInput = rInput.Cells(1).Value                  'Input range as string
    sFml = Replace(kFml, "#RNG", "B:B")             'Update Lookup Range Formula with Common Range (change as required)
    
    Select Case rScope.Cells(1).Value

    Case "AAA"
        sReturn = "FINE"                            'Scope's Default Return
        sFml = Replace(sFml, "#WSH", Sheet3.Name)   'Update Lookup Range Formula with Worksheet Name

    Case Else
        sReturn = "ALSO FINE"                       'Scope's Default Return
        sFml = Replace(sFml, "#WSH", Sheet4.Name)   'Update Lookup Range Formula with Worksheet Name

    End Select

    aLookup = Application.Evaluate(sFml)                                                'Scope's Lookup Range to Array as Text
    If IsError(Application.Match(sInput, aLookup, 0)) Then sReturn = "PLEASE CHECK"     'Validate presence of Input in Lookup Array

    Match_ƒLookup = sReturn

End Function
```