# VBA vlookup between sheets in the same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Im looping through the values of column B in "PaidSent" sheet, I want to output the result of the VLOOKUP into column L of "PaidSent" sheet. The VLOOKUP needs to refer to "Sheet1" where there the reference columns are. This is my macro:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws1, ws2, wsCopyTo As Worksheet
Dim MyStringVar1 As String

Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("SoloMexico")
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set wsCopyFrom = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsCopyTo = wb.Worksheets("SoloMexico")

Set rng = ws1.Range("B2")

With ws1
On Error Resume Next 'add this because if value is not found, vlookup fails, you get 1004
MyStringVar1 = Application.VLookup(rng, ws2.Range("I:O").Value, 7, False)
On Error GoTo 0
If MyStringVar1 = "" Then MsgBox "Item not found" Else MsgBox MyStringVar1
End With

ws2.Range("O6:O" & ws2.Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
ws1.Range("L2:L" & ws1.Range("L" & ws1.Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

I'm having trouble with the VLOOKUP because it doesn't find anything and when it finds an empty value,it stops searching for the rest of the values, i tried copying the result from the VLOOKUP and paste them into "Paidsent" but it COPY/PASTE the original values and not the VLOOKUP result.

How can i correct this ?

Comment: You might consider the late-bound approach with `Application.VLookup` as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064104/9245853).

Comment: Still does the same thing, pastes the original values and not the ones from the vlookup

Comment: You might consider [edit]ing your question with the revised attempt.

Comment: Done already, i've tried with other forms of doing the VLOOKUP but just doesn't work

Comment: One does not use `On Error Resume Next` with `Application.Vlookup`, rather `IsError`.

Comment: Also, `ws2.Range("O6:O" & ws2.Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy` - you haven't changed the values in column O. "i tried copying the result from the VLOOKUP" - the result of the VLOOKUP is `MyStringVar1`, which is different from the values in column O.