# Challenge setting textbox value from combobox

Tags: excel, vba

This boring little form is to be used by me and some others when we're unloading crop for by buddy.

[image: Simple Data Entry Form]

What I want to do is to populate the Grain Type and Variety based on the selection in the Field ComboBox. Grain Type and Variety are comboboxes now because I haven't figured this out so they are manually selected at present.

So here is the `on_click` sub

```
Private Sub cmbField_Change()

    Dim FieldChoice As String
    Dim Grain
    Dim Variety
    
    FieldChoice = cmbField.Value
    
    MsgBox FieldChoice
       
    Grain = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FieldChoice, Worksheets("Seeding_Database").Range("Fields"), 3, 0)

End Sub
```

The error is in setting the value of Grain. The `VLookup` throws 1004 runtime error and I cannot tell why. I know the value of `FieldChoice` is in the Range. I know this because the choices in the Field Combobox are from the same Range. The user is choosing a known value in the `VLookup` range. So although I should have some error handling, that'll come later.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064104/9245853 for the error handling when you get to that point.

Comment: How many columns does the "Fields" range have?

Comment: Bigben - 4, Fieldname, seeded acres, grain and variety.  I want the value from column 3.

Comment: Is the field choice a number, or text like "Field 1"?

Comment: Text and I made a rookie error. I defined the range as only the first column. Oops. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: That was it. The range was improperly defined. 

Here is the sub now:

Private Sub cmbField_Change()

    Dim FieldChoice As String
    Dim Grain As String
    Dim Variety As String
    
    FieldChoice = cmbField.Value
    
    MsgBox FieldChoice
       
    Grain = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FieldChoice, Worksheets("Seeding_Database").Range("Seeded_Fields"), 3, 0)
    
    MsgBox Grain
    
    Variety = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FieldChoice, Worksheets("Seeding_Database").Range("Seeded_Fields"), 4, 0)
    
    MsgBox Variety

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Closing out my own question because I figured it out. I chose to do it here myself because certainly someone else could have this problem.

My problem was not actually in any of the code. It was all correct. What was wrong, was the Range definition itself.

My original mistake was setting the range to only the Fields in the Seeding_Database range because I wanted to populate the Field combobox with only the fields that had been seeded.

Then I reused that same range without remembering that the range was only one column and didn't have the values needed for the vlookup.

Here is it corrected now: (Notice the range name has changed because I still want the Fields range for it's original purpose)

Private Sub cmbField_Change()

```
Dim FieldChoice As String
Dim Grain As String
Dim Variety As String

FieldChoice = cmbField.Value

MsgBox FieldChoice
   
Grain = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FieldChoice, Worksheets("Seeding_Database").Range("Seeded_Fields"), 3, 0)

MsgBox Grain

Variety = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FieldChoice, Worksheets("Seeding_Database").Range("Seeded_Fields"), 4, 0)

MsgBox Variety
```

End Sub

Comment: You could use the ListIndex property to get the row of the selected field and then use that to get the grain and variety.