# Function with VLOOKUP returning FALSE

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, vlookup

I'm trying to send e-mails to a different To and CC based on two pieces of  information (same row of Column A and Column F) in the same sheet.

[image]

My idea is to check if Column F = 'X' and then search for the To and CC in another sheet with VLOOKUP function.

The VLOOKUP function is returning False. I know that the problem is in the RC argument of VLOOKUP.

A minor issue is how to go to the next info (that is, next Value) and not the next row, because the data can have multiple lines with same info at Column A and continue to send the e-mails.

Also, can't lock the cells because this macro will run weekly with variable amount of data.

```vb
Sub manda_email()

Dim cc_padrao As String
Dim Elt As String
Dim Bt As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim lojas As Range
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Dim saudacao, corpo, dif, final As String
[enter image description here][1]
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
cc_padrao = "Carlos@email; Son@email; Lau@email"
Set lojas = Range("A2:A" & Lastrow)

'Consultar Band
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5],Bandeiras!R2C1:R170C2,2,0)"
Range("F2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F" & Lastrow)

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   
For Each lj In lojas

    If lj.End(xlToRight).Value = "Elt" Then

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .display

            'So far, so good!
            .To = GR_Elt()
            .cc = cc_padrao & CR_Elt()
            .Subject = "Dif | " & "Eletro" & lj 'lj here would be the cell value'

            saudacao = "Olá, " & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
            corpo = "Por gentileza, " & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
            dif = "Incluir tabela" & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
            final = "Por gentileza, enviar." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Aguardo breve retorno." & Chr(10) & Chr(10)     
            .BODY = saudacao & corpo & dif & final

            'Email.send
        End With  

    Else

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
            .display
            .To = GR_Bt() & EN_Bt()
            .cc = cc_padrao & CR_Bt()
            .Subject = "Dif | " & "BT" & lj           

            saudacao = "Olá, " & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
            corpo = "Por gentileza, " & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
            dif = "Incluir tabela" & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
            final = "Por gentileza, enviar." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Aguardo breve retorno." & Chr(10) & Chr(10)

            .BODY = saudacao & corpo & dif & final

            'Email.send 
        End With

    End If

Next

End Sub

Public Function GR_Elt() As String
    GR_Elt = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC,'Contatos Elt'!C1:C4,4,0)"
    Exit Function
End Function

Public Function GR_Bt() As String
    GR_Bt = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'Contatos Bt'!C1:C3,4,0)"
    Exit Function
End Function

Public Function CR_Elt() As String
    CR_Elt = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'Contatos Elt'!C1:C6,4,0)"
    Exit Function
End Function

Public Function CR_Bt() As String
    CR_Bt = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'Contatos Bt'!C1:C5,4,0)"
    Exit Function
End Function

Public Function EN_Bt() As String
    EN_Bt = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'Contatos Bt'!C1:C4,4,0)"
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: `GR_Elt = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC,'Contatos Elt'!C1:C4,4,0)"`. Note the two `=` in this line (ignore the one inside the quotes). That means the right-hand side is evaluated and returns a boolean. I.e., it is `False` that the `ActiveCell` contains the formula `"=VLOOKUP(RC,'Contatos Elt'!C1:C4,4,0)"`.

Comment: That makes sense. The correction would be separate in two lines? Because the way I see it, if I take out the "GR_Elt = " the function won't return the value of VLOOKUP (or am I wrong?)

Comment: Probably you should use `Application.Vlookup` and not use a formula at all.

Comment: I've tried to use App.Vlookup, but VBA says it cannot call the VLOOKUP in the Worksheet class. Have no idea why it isn't working.

Comment: [Use `Application.Vlookup`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063214/how-to-error-handle-1004-error-with-worksheetfunction-vlookup).

Comment: Still won't return anything but error. Tried to do this:

Public Function GR_Elt(n As Integer) As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Sheets("Contatos Elt")
    rng = sht.Range("A2:D79")
    GR_Elt = Application.VLookup(n, rng, 4, False)
    Exit Function
End Function

In the sub-procedure I call the function like this: GR_Elt(n = lj)

Comment: Missing a `Set` before `rng =`. Also, side note, but you don't need `Exit Function`.

Comment: Didn't work it either. I think the problem could be related to the argument As Integer but the Function as String, making them incompatible. Does it make sense to you?