# VBA error 424 "Object Required" for Excel vlookup in Word Macro

Tags: excel, vba, object, ms-word, vlookup

I'm trying to do an MS Excel vlookup on an MS Excel workbook from a MS Word macro.

My MS Word macro:

```vb
Sub Salary_Step1()

bool_debug = True ' set to False once code is working

Dim int_PayGrade As Integer
Dim xlApp, xlWorkBook As Object
Dim str_Locality As String, str_WorkBook As String, str_Worksheet As String

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

int_PayGrade = ActiveDocument.FormFields("PayGrade").DropDown.Value - 1
str_Locality = ActiveDocument.FormFields("Locality").Result

If (bool_debug) Then MsgBox ("PayGrade = " & int_PayGrade & vbCrLf & "Locality = " & str_Locality)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

str_WorkBook = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Documents\Announcement Postion Template\PayScales.xlsx"
str_Worksheet = ActiveDocument.FormFields("Locality").Result
If Dir(str_WorkBook) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Cannot find the designated workbook: " & str_WorkBook, vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

With xlApp
    .Visible = True ' set to False when code is working
    Set xlWorkBook = .Workbooks.Open(FileName:=str_WorkBook, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMru:=False)
    With xlWorkBook
        Set xlSheet = .Worksheets(str_Worksheet)
        With xlSheet
            .Select ' comment out when code is working
            int_salary_step1 = .WorksheetFunction.VLookup(int_PayGrade, Sheet1.Range("A1:K16"), 2, False)
            int_salary_step10 = .WorksheetFunction.VLookup(int_PayGrade, Sheet1.Range("A1:K16"), 11, False)
        End With
        .Close False ' set to True when code is working
    End With
    .Quit
End With

If (bool_debug) Then MsgBox ("Pay Step 1 = " & int_salary_step1 & vbCrLf & "Pay Step 10 = " & int_salary_step10)

Set xlWorkBook = Nothing: Set xlApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I know

- the workbook is being opened, because of
  the `.Visible = True ' set to False when code is working` in the first `With`
- the correct sheet is being selected because of
  the `.Select ' comment out when code is working` in the third `With`.

I get

> Error 404 Object Required

when I try to execute either of:

```vb
int_salary_step1 = .WorksheetFunction.VLookup(int_PayGrade, Sheet1.Range("A1:K16"), 2, False)

int_salary_step10 = .WorksheetFunction.VLookup(int_PayGrade, Sheet1.Range("A1:K16"), 11, False)
```

I `Dim`ed `xlApp`, `xlWorkBook` and `xlSheet` as `Object`s, and `Set` each one. I think I'm working with an `Object` when I try `.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(...)`.

Comment: `Sheet1` is not `Set`. You need `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, which would flag `Sheet1` as an undeclared variable.

Comment: The declaration `Dim xlApp, xlWorkBook As Object` only declares `xlWorkbook` as an object, `xlApp` is untyped and is therefore a variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments from BigBen and Timothy Rylatt, I added `Option Explicit`, discovered that I hadn't `Dim`ed all of my variables, and in particular `sheet1`, which was a typo, it should have been `xlSheet`.  So my bad.

But having `Dim`ed all of my variables, I got a

```
Run-time error '438'
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

For no good reason really, I tried

```
            int_salary_step1 = .Application.VLookup(int_PayGrade, Sheet1.Range("A1:K16"), 2, False)
            int_salary_step10 = .Application.VLookup(int_PayGrade, Sheet1.Range("A1:K16"), 11, False)
```

as opposed to

```
            int_salary_step1 = .WorksheetFunction.VLookup(int_PayGrade, Sheet1.Range("A1:K16"), 2, False)
            int_salary_step10 = .WorksheetFunction.VLookup(int_PayGrade, Sheet1.Range("A1:K16"), 11, False)
```

and, Viola!, it runs properly!

So thanks BigBen and Timothy Rylatt!

Comment: `For no good reason really` - there was a good reason though, which was that this was inside `With xlSheet`, and [`WorksheetFunction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.worksheetfunction) is indeed not a [property of `Worksheet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet#properties), but a [property of `Application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application(object)#properties). Note that by this replacement you have [changed the behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064104/11683) of your code.

Comment: GSerg--right!  Thanks.