# Not sure if I declared my variables correctly?

Tags: excel, vba

When I run this code, I get an error saying that I have a run time error 6

```
Dim ProjectNumber As Integer
Dim XProjectFolder As String


ProjectNumber = projectinfosheet.Range("B10")

If Target.Address = "$B$10" Then

    XProjectFolder = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ProjectNumber & "*", FolderRng, 1, False)
    projectinfosheet.Range("E1").Value = XProjectFolder
    MsgBox XProjectFolder
End if
```

But when I comment Dim ProjectNumber As Integer out, the code run smoothly. Am I dimensioning my variables incorrectly?

Comment: What if you change it from an Integer to a Long?

Comment: hey that works!

Comment: Integers have a limit of 32,767, so you must have exceeded that.

Comment: hmm...I'm still getting errors when I change to different project numbers. The error this time is Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class

Comment: Note: You have almost no reason to use `Integer` in VBA nowadays so just declare them as `Long` moving forward.

Comment: Like what number for example?

Comment: 141864   ...... <---ignore those dots. I had to use them to post a comment

Comment: The code runs smoothly when I type in 139280. But numbers higher than that seems to give me issues.

Comment: Could you post the complete code? The declaration and reference to `FolderRng` are missing. There are a few events that have `Target` as an argument. A `VLookup` with the third argument set to `1` makes little sense. Please describe when and what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: For the error regarding `VLookup`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063214/how-to-error-handle-1004-error-with-worksheetfunction-vlookup)