# Type Mismatch in VLookup using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, type-mismatch

I am creating a spreadsheet app for automatically generating email content for my team. Not everyone uses the same email client and so the goal is to write data to the Microsoft Clipboard for easy pasting.

To preserve formatting, I created a table containing the various chunks of text to be concatenated and written to the Clipboard. I have four email templates and everything works except for one.

Here is a piece of the code:

```vb
If EmailTemplate = "How-To" Then

    EmailSub = "OAS: How-To Guide"
    
    EmailCode1 = Evaluate("VLookup(Email_Type,EmailBodies,2,False)")
    
    RepEmail = Evaluate("VLookup(Email_Type, EmailBodies, 3, False)")
    
    EmailCode2 = Evaluate("VLookup(Email_Type, EmailBodies, 4, False)")
    
    RepCalendar = Evaluate("VLookup(Email_Type, EmailBodies, 5, False)")
    
    EmailCode3 = Evaluate("VLookup(Email_Type, EmailBodies, 6, False)")
    
ElseIf EmailTemplate = "PQW" Then

    EmailSub = "When You Are Ready, Please Tell Us About Your Project Requirements"
    
    EmailCode1 = Evaluate("VLookup(Email_Type,EmailBodies,2,False)")
    
    RepEmail = Evaluate("VLookup(Email_Type, EmailBodies, 3, False)")
    
    EmailCode2 = Evaluate("VLookup(Email_Type, EmailBodies, 4, False)")
    
    RepCalendar = Evaluate("VLookup(Email_Type, EmailBodies, 5, False)")
    
    EmailCode3 = Evaluate("VLookup(Email_Type, EmailBodies, 6, False)")
```

I am referencing a table using the Vlookup function.

The first condition `EmailTemplate = "How-To"` works however for "PQW" I get a type mismatch error when assigning variable EmailCode1.

For "How-To" the text in the cell is:

> Thank you for your interest in Open Automation Software.  Please see the links below for guidance on accomplishing your specified requirements:

For "PQW" it is:

> Please tell us more about your project requirements.  By filling out this worksheet, it will make it easier for us to help you focus your efforts on evaluating the parts of our software that are important to you.
>
> Please take a few minutes to fill out and email back to

Both contain line breaks and both contain only text. All variables you see within the code are of String data-type.

I have tried:

1. Setting the cell data-type to Text
2. Verifying that the string term being searched by Vlookup matches exactly  what is presented in the table.
3. Changing data-type of all variables to Variant.
4. Deleting the row in question in my table and manually creating a copy.
5. Entering the exact same formula in a cell to see if it returns the proper data - it does.

The same formula and datatypes work for every other condition.

[image: See image for example of VLookup formula returning proper data in cell.]

Comment: My guess would be that the `Vlookup` fails to find a match.

Comment: Btw, consider avoiding repetition. `EmailCode1`, `RepEmail`, `EmailCode2`, `RepCalendar`, and `EmailCode3` are determined in the same manner for both "How-To" and "PQW", which suggests they could be outside the `If...ElseIf`.

Comment: Try using `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` instead of evaluating a string; that's going to throw a trappable run-time error instead of returning a `Variant/Error` with the `#N/A` error result. Anything that may possibly return a `Variant/Error` should never be assigned to anything other than a `Variant`; then you can use `If IsError(theReturnedVariant)` to handle `#N/A`. Alternatively, you can use the late-bound `Application.VLookup` to do the same - either way, `Evaluate` is out of place.

Comment: Are these variables declared? With a type?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yes, they are all declared as Strings.

Comment: @BigBen I thought of that too, but the identical function returns the proper data when used in a spreadsheet cell - so it's clear the input does match an item in the table.

Comment: As suggested, use `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup` or `Application.Vlookup` instead of `Evaluate`. I'd prefer `Application.Vlookup`, and assign the result to a `Variant`, and test if it's an error using `IsError`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I will try this solutions with Applicaton.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup.  THis was the original method I was using but ran into a similarly perplexing issue where I would get an error saying the WorksheetFunction object could not be retrieved from the application class, even when it worked fine in a different instance earlier in the code.  I will try again, though.

Comment: That error means that the Vlookup didn't find a match. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063214/how-to-error-handle-1004-error-with-worksheetfunction-vlookup).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yes, unfortunately I am still getting that same error.  Although, I got the error incorrect.  The error is that Excel cannot get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction Class.

Comment: Verify the parameterization, and if you're using the early-bound version (i.e. you get parameter tooltips), then you need an `On Error` statement to redirect execution when the VLookup function doesn't find a match. Otherwise the error is unhandled and that'll stop your macro dead in its tracks.

Comment: As for the error, as BigBen said it means the VLookup did not get a match, i.e. on a worksheet you'd be getting `#N/A` for it.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon But I don't, which is what is confusing me.  I just updated my post with an image of what I'm referring to.

Thanks again.  I've worked with VBA a fair deal but still would not consider myself very experienced.  I really appreciate all the help.

Comment: At this point I'm suspecting it's [implicit ActiveSheet references](https://rubberduckvba.com/inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference) throwing a wrench. `Evaluate` operates in the context of whatever the ActiveSheet happens to be. Not sure how you're passing the ranges to VLookup, but unqualified, `Range` alone is also likely to implicitly referring to whatever the ActiveSheet is (is your code written in a standard module?). To fix this you need to qualify `Range` with an explicit `Worksheet` object, so `theSheet.Range("...")` instead of just `Range("...")` (see link).

Comment: Actually no, it has to be the named ranges that are referred to in the formulas - if they fail to resolve, they'll be `#REF!` errors, and that makes VLOOKUP return `#REF!` instead of `#N/A`. Do you get `True` if you do `Debug.Print Application.VLookup(...) = CVErr(xlErrREF)` (that's error 2023; `#N/A` would be error 2042 / `CVErr(xlErrNA)`)? You need to pass VLookup an actual `Range` object when you use it from VBA. Assuming the names are workbook-scoped that's `ThisWorkbook.Names("theName").RefersToRange`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon That was it!  I was referencing a table by its name in the spreadsheet but had not explicitly defined it as a range object within the Macro.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Awesome! I've posted my draft answer so this question can be marked as "answered" (you can check the "accepted" checkmark near the top of the post to do that) - cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It has to be the names. Resolve them yourself and pass VLOOKUP an actual `Range` object instead of a name: Excel can (does) resolve named ranges before it passes them to the function, but VBA doesn't know it has to do this and attempts to pass VLOOKUP the names you've given it, but VLOOKUP expects `Range` objects.

You can validate whether that's indeed the case by checking the specific error code returned by the late-bound VLookup function against `CVErr(xlErrRef)` (the variant/error value for "error 2023" / `#REF!` worksheet errors).

If the function returns "error 2042" / `#N/A` worksheet error, you can validate against `CVErr(xlErrNA)` - and that would mean the lookup is failing to find what it's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
If EmailTemplate = "How-To" Then

    EmailSub = "OAS: How-To Guide"
    
    EmailCode1 = Evaluate("VLookup(Email_Type,EmailBodies,2,False)")
    
    RepEmail = Evaluate("VLookup(Email_Type, EmailBodies, 3, False)")
    
    EmailCode2 = Evaluate("VLookup(Email_Type, EmailBodies, 4, False)")
    
    RepCalendar = Evaluate("VLookup(Email_Type, EmailBodies, 5, False)")
    
    EmailCode3 = Evaluate("VLookup(Email_Type, EmailBodies, 6, False)")
    
ElseIf EmailTemplate = "PQW" Then

    EmailSub = "When You Are Ready, Please Tell Us About Your Project Requirements"
    
    EmailCode1 = Evaluate("VLookup(Email_Type,EmailBodies,2,False)")
    
    RepEmail = Evaluate("VLookup(Email_Type, EmailBodies, 3, False)")
    
    EmailCode2 = Evaluate("VLookup(Email_Type, EmailBodies, 4, False)")
    
    RepCalendar = Evaluate("VLookup(Email_Type, EmailBodies, 5, False)")
    
    EmailCode3 = Evaluate("VLookup(Email_Type, EmailBodies, 6, False)")
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?