# VBA Index Match got a Type Mismatch Error

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match, type-mismatch

I am trying to use index&Match to lookup values between 2 sheets. One sheet is defined as "Destination" and the other sheet is defined as "Origin".

My code got type mismatch error. I tested the function logic and the formula is working in the excel. I looked at other's similar issues here but still cannot solve it. It would be much appreciated for any suggestions.

```
Sub CalculateTracker()
    Dim LastRow As long
    Dim Destination As Worksheet
    Set Destination =Worksheets("sheet1")
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Origin As Worksheet
    Set Origin = Worksheet("sheet2")

    With Worksheet("sheet1")
         LastRow=.Cells(.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For i=2 To LastRow
        With Worksheets("sheet1")
             Cells(i,28).Value=WorksheetFunction.ifError(WorksheetFuncion.Index(Origin.Range("AZ:AZ"),Application.Match(Destination.Range("X" & i),Origin.Range("B:B"),0)),0)
        End With

    Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: Use `IsError` to test if `Application.Match` returned an error.

Comment: You also have a typo with `WorksheetFuncion.Index` missing a `t` which would cause errors if that is in the source code.

Comment: You cannot use `WorksheetFunction.ifError` to handle run-time errors thrown by other`WorksheetFunction.xxx` calls

Comment: Another typo `With Worksheet("Sheet1")` missing an `s` to `Worksheet` and at `Set Origin= Worksheet("sheet2")` also

Comment: Thanks for all comments. I changed IfError to IsError, still not working. I am new to VBA. It would be awesome to have more detailed code debugging explanation.

Comment: And please ignore all typo mistakes. I manually typed everything rather than copying my code directly. It's expected to have some typo mistakes.

Comment: BigBen suggestion means that divide your complex statement into parts (one-by-one), and use `On error resume next`  and `On Error Goto 0` statements around the statements. After every line test the `Error` value and display an error message to see what causes the error.

Comment: @Blackcat - no that is not my suggestion at all. Nowhere did I suggest using `On Error Resume Next` or `On Error GoTo 0`. I suggested `IsError`, which is very different.

Comment: @big Dig deeper in the words. With this mode you can get more detailed error information and it is not very different, but the result is better because of the previously mentioned. But OK this was my suggestion, based on your comment.

Comment: @Blackcat - you may be thinking of using `WorksheetFunction.Match`. OP is using `Application.Match`, which requires an entirely different approach. One does not use `On Error` here at all, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064104).

Comment: @Big To my knowledge Application. and Worksheetfunction. is the same. For my Excel sure.

Comment: @Blackcat - no, they are not the same. `Application.` is the late-bound form of `WorksheetFunction.` and requires an entirely different error-handling approach, which is exactly the point of this question. Highly suggest you read the thread linked in my last comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IsError` to test if `Match` returned an error.

```
Dim result As Variant
result = Application.Match(Destination.Range("X" & i),Origin.Range("B:B"),0)

If Not IsError(result) Then
    Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i,28).Value = Origin.Range("AZ:AZ").Cells(result)
Else
    Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i,28).Value = 0
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

### Index/Match in VBA (Late Bound)

[image]

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CalculateTracker()
    
    Const DST_FIRST_ROW As Long = 2
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim Origin As Worksheet: Set Origin = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    Dim Destination As Worksheet: Set Destination = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim dlRow As Long
    
    With Destination
        dlRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    If dlRow < DST_FIRST_ROW Then Exit Sub ' no data
    
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = DST_FIRST_ROW To dlRow
        With Application
             Destination.Cells(r, "AB").Value _
                 = .IfError(.Index(Origin.Range("AZ:AZ"), _
                 .Match(Destination.Cells(r, "X"), Origin.Range("B:B"), 0)), 0)
        End With
    Next r

End Sub
```