# VBA: I try to highlight a cell selected by VLookup (active cell are "VLookedup")

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Below is the code I try.
This code works without any error in Excel for Mac, but does not work in windows with Error 424 "Object Required".
I can't figure out the reason why I cannot make it work in Excel in window and seek a solution.

I really appreciate your advise.

Combine ConditionalFormat and VLookup
"VLookedup" values are on columns B in Sheet2.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 
 If Target.Cells.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
 With Me.Range("A1:I20") '★
 .FormatConditions.Delete
 If Target.Value <> "" Then
 .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
 Formula1:=Application.VLookup(Target.Value, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
 .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 28
 End If
 End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: I've copied your code into a workbook on Win10/32-bit Excel and it works as expected with no error. It might help if you provide a sample of the data you are using in both sheets.

Comment: You need to copy the code into the correct **sheet module** (e.g. `Sheet1`), not into a standard module (e.g. `Module1`) or the `Thisworkbook` module. This code runs automatically so don't try to run it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it in correct module and you will probably add error handling.

Correct place for code:
[image]

You will also get an error with vlookup: `run time error 5` when the vlookup is ["out of range error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063214/how-to-error-handle-1004-error-with-worksheetfunction-vlookup)". This will occur if you for example click on Cell A1 in my example below or don't find any result.
I added some quick error handling to make it work.

This is the result in my sheet, where B column have the formula (`=VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$E$5,2,FALSE`). D and E column is my vlookup table, and when I click on any cell in A column, excel highlight the relationship.

[image]