# Runtime Error 1004 - when range input uses double digit cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the following code to pull data from a separate worksheet and fill cells based on two criteria matches `[Ticker]` and `[Account]`. Any of the `[names]` reference whole columns in the second worksheet where the data is input.

My code is set to mimic the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(WS2!E:E, MATCH(1, (WS1!B8=WS2!B:B)*(WS1!$M$3=WS2!C:C), 0)), 0)
```

This matches the cell in `column B` to the `[Ticker]` (`WS2 column b`) and the locked `M3` cell to an `[Account]`(`WS2 column C`) and outputs the `[Amount]`(`WS2 column E`). There are 300+ rows that all have this formula, (with changing `B#` references).

I am trying to stop them from constantly updating by adding a macro to only do this process once and increase the speed of my workflow. The desired result is that it would go down the 13th column, match the two criteria, and output mktval into each cell there is a match.

Running into two problems:

1 - the match is not an exact match. Its referencing different `[Amount]`s

2 - I get a **runtime 1004 error** if the range has a double digit number

I'm looking to use `Set valcol = .Range("M8:M300")`, if I use `M8:M9` it runs, but once I use `M10` I get the **runtime error**. Any advice helps, thanks!

```
Sub UpdateReport()
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WS1")
Dim valcol As Range
Dim therow As Long
Dim thecol As Integer
thecol = 13
Set valcol = .Range("M8:M10")
Dim mktval
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For therow = 8 To (valcol.Cells.Count + 7)
        mktval = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index([Amount], Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("WS1").Cells(therow, 2), [Ticker], 0) _
        + Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("WS1").Cells(3, thecol), [Account], 0), 0)
        If Not IsError(mktval) Then
            Worksheets("WS1").Cells(therow, thecol).Value = mktval
        Else
            Worksheets("WS1").Cells(therow, thecol).Value = 0
        End If
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

I've tried to mess around with different conventions but can not find one that solves my issue.

Comment: Could you share the Excel formula that your code is supposed to 'mimic' with a more extensive description? Some sample data as text and screenshots including the desired result would also help.

Comment: I've included some context I hope you find helpful. Hard to produce screenshots given the nature of the work :)

Comment: You are using `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` and testing the result with `IsError`. It does not return an error, it [raises it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064104/11683).

Answer (score 1):

### A Two-Column Match in VBA Using Formula

[image]

```vb
Sub UpdateReport()

    Const SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMN_1 As String = "Ticker"
    Const SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMN_2 As String = "Account"
    Const SRC_RETURN_COLUMN As String = "Amount"
    Const DST_NAME As String = "WS1"
    Const DST_LOOKUP_CELL_1 As String = "B8"
    Const DST_LOOKUP_CELL_2 As String = "M$3"
    Const DST_RETURN_COLUMN As String = "M"

    Dim Formula2 As String: Formula2 _
        = "=IFERROR(INDEX(" & SRC_RETURN_COLUMN & ",MATCH(1,(" _
        & DST_LOOKUP_CELL_1 & "=" & SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMN_1 & ")*(" _
        & DST_LOOKUP_CELL_2 & "=" & SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMN_2 & "), 0)), 0)"

    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(DST_NAME)
    
    Dim drg As Range
    
    With dws.Range(DST_LOOKUP_CELL_1)
        Set drg = .Resize(dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, .Column) _
            .End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1).EntireRow.Columns(DST_RETURN_COLUMN)
    End With
    
    With drg
        .Formula2 = Formula2
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Ticker` is a text and `Account` is a number (text requires additional quotes), you can try the code like this:

```
Dim mktval, cond
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For therow = 8 To (valcol.Cells.Count + 7)
      cond = Evaluate("(""" & Worksheets("WS1").Cells(therow, 2) & """ = Ticker) * 
 (" & Worksheets("WS1").Cells(3, thecol) & " = Account)")
      mktval = Application.Index([Amount], Application.Match(1, cond, 0))
...
```